# requestFeature with action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

So I was looking at google's api demos for action bars and they have this

```
// The Action Bar is a window feature. The feature must be requested
    // before setting a content view. Normally this is set automatically
    // by your Activity's theme in your manifest. The provided system
    // theme Theme.WithActionBar enables this for you. Use it as you would
    // use Theme.NoTitleBar. You can add an Action Bar to your own themes
    // by adding the element <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    // to your style definition.
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
```

but when I tried to add the last line of code `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);`  My app just dies on start up. So what does it really do?

Comment: read your log cat and post a copy of the exception that is causing your app to crash.

Comment: Most likely, you are calling it too late. `requestFeature()` needs to be called before `setContentView()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah that was the reason it wasn't working. Thanks. It was weird because it only generated an error in the emulator and not a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

The secret is the order of the callings.The requestfeature must be called before fill nothing. I do it in this order and works fine:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getSupportActionBar().hide();
setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late, did you try

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR)
```