# Android Activity without ActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I have different `Activities` in my App and in all of them I do not want the `Action Bar`. I cannot find how to disable it. I have tried to find an attribute to apply it to the `main_activity.xml` but so far I did not find anything. Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Haha, I have been stuck at that point a while ago as well, so I am glad I can help you out with a solution, that worked for me at least :)

What you want to do is define a new style within values/styles.xml so it looks like this

```
<resources>
    <style name = "AppTheme" parent = "android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name = "NoActionBar" parent = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name = "android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name = "android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Only the NoActionBar style is intresting for you. At last you have to set is as your application's theme in the AndroidManifest.xml so it looks like this

```
<application
    android:allowBackup = "true"
    android:icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label = "@string/app_name"
    android:theme = "@style/NoActionBar"   <!--This is the important line-->
    >
    <activity
    [...]
```

Comment: This one didn't help, used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790070/upgraded-to-appcompat-v22-1-0-and-now-getting-illegalargumentexception-appcompa instead

Comment: Are you sure it is `item name = "android:windowActionBar"`? I had to use it without `android:` prefix to make it work. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26515159/1000551)

Comment: This answer is almost 4 years old, there may be something different by now. Thank you for sharing the solution that worked for you though!

Comment: Use <item name = "windowNoTitle">true</item> instead of <item name = "android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

Comment: this work for flutter too.

Answer (score 91):

There are multiple ways of doing this.

## 1) Change the theme in Android Manifest

Below the Application element, you will find theme tag. Replace it with this one -

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

If you are using AppCompat, use `@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`.

This will set the theme for all activities. If you don't need the action bar in a specific acitivity, then set the theme in the activity container, ie

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" ...>
```

You may also set `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` theme in the styles and use it later on.

---

## 2) Create a Custom Theme

Add this in `res/values/styles.xml`

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
     <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
     <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and then set it as your activity's theme in Manifest:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" ... />
```

---

## 3) Dynamically Remove the Action Bar

Put this code in the `onCreate` method **before setting content view** -

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
getActionBar().hide();
```

If you are using the support library use `getSupportActionBar()`.

Comment: This one didn't help, used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790070/upgraded-to-appcompat-v22-1-0-and-now-getting-illegalargumentexception-appcompa instead.

Comment: That's because you will be using appcompat. Thanks for pointing it out. I have made the changes.

Comment: This is for me the more completed answer.

Answer (score 21):

If you're using `AppCompat`, declare your activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` as follows:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SomeActivity"
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

Answer (score 18):

Considering everyone is posting older ways of hiding the ActionBar here is the proper way of implementing it within styles for AppCompat support library. Which I highly suggest moving toward if you haven't already.

Simply removing the ActionBar

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

If you are using the appcompat support libraries, this is the easiest and recommended way of hiding the ActionBar to make full screen or start implementing to toolbar within your layouts.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Your Toolbar Color-->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>

    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>

    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated,
     which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
     colorControlHighlight, and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
</style>
```

Then to change your toolbar color

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id=”@+id/my_awesome_toolbar”
    android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:minHeight=”?attr/actionBarSize”
    android:background=”?attr/primary” />
```

Last note: Your Activity class should extend AppCompatActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

<!--Activity Items -->

}
```

Comment: Thanks, Eugene H. Well, I tried your code changing colors with random values. It works, as it could work without color definitions. Due to NoActionBar.

Comment: @CoolMind You are correct. I just added some typical styles attributes with AppCompat. I will add descriptions within the answer.

Comment: Eugene, yes, moving from ActionBar to a ToolBar is a good idea.

Comment: This is probably the best solution and should be accepted as an answer. It's based on the latest technique available in Android dev studio, thus recommended for use. Kudos to Eugene H.

Answer (score 12):

Default style you getting in res/value/style.xml like

```
  <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
```

And just the below like in your activity tag,

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want most of your activities to have an action bar you would probably inherit your base theme from the default one (this is automatically generated by Android Studio per default):

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

And then add a special theme for your bar-less activity:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoTitle" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="actionBarTheme">@null</item>
    </style>
```

For me, setting *actionBarTheme* to *@null* was the solution.

Finally setup the activity in your manifest file:

```
<activity ... android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoTitle" ... >
```

Answer (score 6):

You may also change inheritance from ActionBarActivity to Activity as written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21815015/2914140).

UPDATE

A good solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28618934/2914140):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

open Manifest and add attribute theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" to activity you want it without actionbar :

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        ...
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 3):

I will try to show it as simple as i can:

DECLARE FULL SCREEN ACTIVITY IN ANDROID MAINIFEST file:

```
<activity
            android:name=".GameActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_game"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

Now in Android studio (if you using it) open your Activity xml file ( in my example activity_game.xml) in designer and select theme (above mobile phone in designer click button with small circle) and then select Mainfest Themes on the left side and then NoTitleBar.Fullscreen.

Hope it will help!

Comment: You can use android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" for AppCompat.

Answer (score 2):

Please find the default theme in styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

And change parent this way

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"
```

Using this theme worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Put this line in your `Activity` in the `Manifest`:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        ...
    </activity>
```

and make sure you didn't put `Toolbar` in your layout

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            />
```

Answer (score -1):

Create an new Style with any name, in my case "Theme.Alert.NoActionBar"

```
<style name="Theme.Alert.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

set its parent as "Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" like in the above code

open AndoridManifest.xml and customize the activity you want to show as Alert Dialog like this

```
    <activity
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Alert.NoActionBar"
        android:name=".activities.UserLoginActivity" />
```

in my app i want show my user login activity as Alert Dialog, these are the codes i used. hope this works for you!!!

Answer (score -1):

It's Really Simple Just go to your `styles.xml` change the parent Theme to either
`Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` or `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionbar` and you are done.. :)

Comment: How is your answer different from Eugene H's?