# Android toolbar error

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am attempting to use a `Toolbar` in my application and I am running into an issue:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set android:windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
```

I do not believe that I am requesting `Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR` anywhere and I am setting the `ActionBar` to false. This is my Style.xml:

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/text_secondary</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="android:ThemeOverlay.Material.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

and this is my toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme">

</Toolbar>
```

and in my layouts I am doing `<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />` and then `setActionBar(toolbar)` in my `onCreate()`. I have seen multiple threads about this but none solve my issue. I should also note I am only supporting 5.0 so I am not using appcompat

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor

Comment: Yes, I saw that thread, and the solution did not work for me

Comment: This `<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>` and this  `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>` aren't the same.

Comment: `windowActionBar` is only used when you are using AppCompat, which like I said, I'm not

Comment: Haaa, you are right, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this style for **your Activity not the Toolbar**.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
   ....
   <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

If you are not using the appCompat library:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
   ....
   <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I tried that as well and it did not work. At first I just used my `AppTheme` as the theme for my toolbar, then I changed it to have it's own theme and placed the `android:windowActionBar` in both and neither worked

Comment: @RyanSayles Post your manifest. Are you setting the style for your activity?

Comment: I have `android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >` in my `<application` but not in any `<activity` I believe I did try that at one point but if I don't include it won't they inherit from the application?