# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I tried to migrate a project from Eclipse to Android studio. Finally I am able to run it, but at a certain point I got this exception, and I found nothing in google about this:

```
04-22 00:08:15.484    9891-9891/hu.illion.kwindoo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hu.illion.kwindoo/hu.illion.kwindoo.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
    ...    
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:360)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:246)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
    at hu.illion.kwindoo.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:73)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
    ...
```

**73. line of MainActivity is:**

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Please advice me if you can.

Comment: Never seen this but perhaps you're using a feature in R.layout.activity_main that requires a different version of the Android API? - Though Android Studio likes to tell you about those things... Goodluck

Comment: post your theme.xml or style.xml and the activity_main.xml

Comment: Can you put your .gradle files in here as well? You probably depend on a old appcompat?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgraded to AppCompat v22.1.0 and now getting IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790070/upgraded-to-appcompat-v22-1-0-and-now-getting-illegalargumentexception-appcompa)

Answer (score 242, accepted):

alternative to @sbaar's answer,

keep `windowActionBar` to `false` and add `windowNoTitle`as well and set it to `true`.

ie

```
   <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Comment: I had to do this to my app after updating to the latest appcompt (22.1) today.  that's all I have changed and my app now works again.

Comment: I don't use custom scheme (I use Theme.AppCompat) but I have the same exception. How to fix that?

Comment: that's strange, but works after switch ActionBarActivity -> AppCompatActivity

Comment: This answer did not work for me. Only @sbaar answer worked. Your theme should inherit from: Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar in addition to those: <item name="windowActionBar">false</item> and <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

Comment: This works for themes that don't have an alternative in ```NoActionBar``` style. In my example it works for ```Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog```

Comment: This works when inheriting from Theme.AppComapt.NoActionBar. Perfect!

Comment: But how set title now?

Comment: please help me. i have that problem. why this code not work for me

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44923662/why-appcompat-does-not-support-the-current-theme-features-windowactionbar-false

Comment: Still not working? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45643107/appcompat-does-not-support-the-current-theme

Comment: I had a similar problem (`com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1` & `compileSdkVersion 24`) when I tried to remove the action bar without setting it to fullscreen: `AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }` and the apparently faulty line in my MainActivity was `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`. Your suggestion fixed it for me (even with `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`), thanks!

Answer (score 42):

Remove

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

from your theme, then make sure you are inheriting from a .NoActionBar Theme, then set your toolbar like normal.

Comment: And why should i modify a thing ? This project was verry well with eclipse for months.

Comment: Because some hours ago Google released their version 22.1 of the support library, causing this issue in your project (and in mine as well). It's just a coincidence, not because of the migration to Android Studio.

Comment: For me, inheriting the theme from .NoActionBar was the key, no element removal was needed.

Answer (score 33):

Make sure that your theme is child from `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`, then in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        ...
</style>
```

Btw, it's a new issue for Support Library 22.1.

Comment: @QadirHussain, No, didn't.

Comment: AppCompat.NoActionBar made all my textView color white use Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar instead

Comment: Doesn't work still https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45643107/appcompat-does-not-support-the-current-theme

Answer (score 16):

Check if you call `setContentView()` after `super.onCreate()`, and not before. This helped in my case.

Comment: Had windowNoTitle and windowActionBar but still didn't work. This fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use this parent in Style.xml
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45643107/appcompat-does-not-support-the-current-theme

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

are at the top of everything this works for me....good luck

Answer (score 3):

in my case i didnt change to .NoActionBar Theme. i just remove android prefix from this item.

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

and the error goes away.

Comment: dont mention it. happy to see your comment.

Answer (score 2):

if you have added `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>`,
then ,you need to add

```
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

add dependency to gradle like this

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by my main Activity extending AppCompatActivity :)

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue somewhat, removed `android:` from my syles.xml as per below;

```
 <!-- caused crash -->
 <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
 <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

 <!-- didn't cause crash -->
 <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
 <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I upgraded the library version from 22.0.0 to 22.1.1 and fixed it by dropping back to the previous version: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0 and go back to using ActionBarActivity, not AppCompatActivity in my Activity classes as required by the newer version of the compatibility library. I'll try again later.

Answer (score 0):

just Use this in your style.xml no other editing is needed

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

<!-- theme customizations -->

<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

don't add anything in to activity file please leave it

```
public class Main extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
} 

@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
int id = item.getItemId();
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java class change `Main extends ActionBarActivity` to `Main extends Activity`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I look for @rewrihitesh answer, and I notice that I **inverted elements order**. Changing from

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

to

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
```

Fix my problem.

Hope it helps !!