# Getting AppCompat does not support the current theme features exception after upgrading to version AppCompat v22.1.0 issue

Tags: android, android-theme, material-design, android-styles, android-appcompat

Previously i was using AppCompat with version 21.1.2 in my project for the purpose of material design toggle with toolbar. But after upgrading to AppCompat v22.1.0, my app has started working weird. I even tried some of the solutions like as follows

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Also applying parent theme as

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

But none of the above solutions was not helpful for me. So kindly please help me by your tips and suggestions to overcome my issue which i am currently facing. I am also posting my styles.xml and logcat error for your reference. Any kind of help would be helpful for me.  Thanks in advance.

styles.xml

```
 <style name="MainActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#F2F2F2</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/yellow</item>
    </style>
```

Logcat Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sample.app/com.sample.app.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:360)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:246)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.sample.app.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

possible duplicate of [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29784124/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-appcompat-does-not-support-the-current-theme)

Answer (score 16):

Thank you all for your replies. I solved my issue on my own by removing the line

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

The error occurred because of adding windowNoTitle two times as follows

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Comment: I don't think it's caused by adding windowNoTitle twice. If you have android:windowNoTitle at all it will cause the crash, so you have to use the name without the android prefix.

Comment: I had a big problem because I wanted to implement a library and I didn't know why it was crashed and your answer fixed it. I just needed the second line of your code. Thanks men

Comment: you are welcome @Alejandroi. Happy that my solution helped you.

Answer (score 7):

Remove .NoActionBar from your MainActivityTheme

```
<style name="MainActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        // ................................................
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove

```
.NoActionBar
```

from your style, because you already use from a `windowNoTitle=false` and `windowActionBar=false` in your Theme.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this help some people

in my case i didnt use .NoActionBar Theme. i just remove android prefix from this item.

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

in addition i use android studio and gradle shot for you is

```
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

fortunately the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

in my case 
i have this code ==>

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

it works when i delete

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

hope this may also help !!!

Answer (score 0):

just Use this in your style.xml no other editing is needed

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

<!-- theme customizations -->

<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
 </style>
```

don't add anything in to activity file please leave it

```
  public class Main extends ActionBarActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
int id = item.getItemId();
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```