# AppCompat does not support the current theme features error

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, styles

This error only occurs when my application goes to this layout :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_surveillance" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new" />
```

I have modified my themes according to this suggestion:
[Getting AppCompat does not support the current theme features exception after upgrading to version AppCompat v22.1.0 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000654/getting-appcompat-does-not-support-the-current-theme-features-exception-after-up)

Here is my styles.xml file:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/background_material_light</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#F2F2F2</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Do you have any idea what is wrong with the code?

Comment: @Dehimb Can you help me with this?