# AppCompat does not support the current theme features, android?

Tags: android, styles, runtimeexception, appcompatactivity

I am using AppCompatActivity

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

This is my theme

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

</style>
```

It is throwing the exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vfi/com.vfi.SplashActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5127)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:363)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:246)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
        at com.vfi.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:17)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2201)
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"  Use this

Comment: duplicate question [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29784124/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-appcompat-does-not-support-the-current-theme

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
   <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   </style>
```

Comment: <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item> I hope u should remove android: in windowNoTitle too

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This Then

```
  <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">


</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```