# Why AppCompat does not support the current theme features windowActionBar: false

Tags: android, android-theme

Why AppCompat does not support the current theme features  { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false

```
    IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2473)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2535)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1396)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5582)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:359)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:328)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.github.paolorotolo.appintro.AppIntroBase.onCreate(AppIntroBase.java:79)
    at com.infos.activities.Activity_Splash.onCreate(Activity_Splash.kt:27)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6321)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread
```

my Theme style

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

    </style>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: post your theme which given to the activity. I believe its parent is not Theme.AppCompat.

Comment: @BLin my Theme added

Comment: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2395

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

go to your `styles.xml` and change you main theme parent with `NoActionBar`
like this

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
 </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check both styles files `styles.xml` and `styles.xml(v21)` in case you have it in your code.

Both styles files must have a parent theme based on the `Theme.AppCompat` theme, or a child of it.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
</style>
```