# Xamarin.Forms: App crash after splash activity

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have splash screen, When I run my app its crash. Here is my splash screen code

If I don't use splash screen app is working fine but when I use splash screen and close my app and run again its crash after splash screen.

```
public class SplashActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
      var mainIntent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity));
        if (Intent.Extras != null)
        {
            mainIntent.PutExtras(Intent.Extras);
        }
        mainIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);

        StartActivity(mainIntent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume the issues is connected with the fact that you are trying to start the already started `SingleTop` activity for the second time.

However, the recommendation is to write a splash screen a bit differently - without needing separate activity. See [this nice blog post by **Adam Pedley**](https://xamarinhelp.com/creating-splash-screen-xamarin-forms/) on splash screen implementation in Xamarin.Forms.

Instead of having a separate activity, you can just temporarily apply a "splash" theme to the main activity, before the activity loads. This is useful, because it makes your app load faster than having a full separate splash screen activity.

Create a style in `Resources/values/styles.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="splashscreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
  </style>
<resources>
```

Set this theme to the `MainActivity` via attribute:

```
[Activity(Label = "Mobile App", 
          Theme = "@style/splashscreen", 
          Icon = "@drawable/icon", 
          MainLauncher = true, 
          ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | 
                                 ConfigChanges.Orientation, 
          LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
 public class MainActivity : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

And then override the `OnCreate` method to set the actual theme back:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.ActionBar);

    // For global use "global::" prefix - global::Android.Resource.Style.ThemeHoloLight
    base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);

    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    ...
}
```

Comment: I know that this post is over a year old, I'm hoping you're still around.  I 've been trying to get a splash screen to work for some time now and now I'm attempting to use your solution.  When I do, I don't see my splash screen and when the app tries to load the next activity I get the error `Message=AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }`.  My app is ready to deploy, I just need to get a splash screen that will work.  Frustrating.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late reply, I am on vacation. Before I return, could you post the styles.xml file you have in your app? Also could you try the following suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29784124/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-appcompat-does-not-support-the-current-theme ?

Comment: The suggestion in the link provided had no effect.  Same problem. I am unable to post my entire Styles.xml in a comment, this is the splash screen style '     <style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
       <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>
     </style>`

Comment: What are the min/target/compile versions of Android you are targeting with your app?

Comment: API 26, API 29.  Xamarin 16.5.000.472 (d16-5@63ed925), Xamarin.Android SDK   10.2.0.100 (d16-5/988c811).

Comment: By any chance, would you be able to make a small repo on GitHub? I would test it locally

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me on .net Maui, It turned out I didn't register the services correctly, so the builder could not generate the page.

Comment: There is no service registration/builder in Xamarin.Forms