# When i'm testing the application in Android Studio i get this error:

Tags: android

here is the error i'm getting and i would appricieate some help from you guys:

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: You must specifiy a layout in the include tag: `<include layout="@layout/layoutID" />`

Here are my `<include layout="@layout/layoutID" />` in activty_main.xml:

```
<include
android:layout="@layout/app_bar"
android:id="@+id/app_bar"/>
```

and here are my app_bar layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
```

Please can someone help me with this. I'm new here in java programming.

Comment: Are you using `Eclipse` or `AndroidStudio`? Try cleaning, opening, closing IDE.

Comment: try adding android.support.v7 jar file.

Comment: @hrskrs I'm using AndroidStudio. I'll try that.

Comment: @AditiParikh I don't know how to add it in AndroidStudio because i started using AndroidStudio yesterday and till then i was using an Eclipse.

Comment: @DusanDimitrijevic you can add libraries using jar file or specifying Maven dependencies. To add jar put it inside the libs folder in the root folder of your main module (usually it called app - on the same level as folders build and src). Then right-click on the module name, select Open Module Settings, choose tab Dependencies and at the bottom press at the Plus sign and choose File dependency.
To add Maven dependency select Library dependency and type artifact name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception message's already containing an answer: change `include android:layout="@layout/app_bar"` to `include layout="@layout/app_bar"`

Comment: Thank you for that, but now i'm getting this error message. By the way i'm trying to add my custom action bar. Here's the message: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead. Can you help me?

Comment: As long as it another exception try to create another question. But this question has asked and answered many times, for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/26515159/3383038

Also consider to thoroughly read exception message - it's often contains the solution like this one