# Action bar supplied by the window decor issue

Tags: android

I am getting following error

Caused by: java.lang.**IllegalStateException**: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.**FEATURE_ACTION_BAR** and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

I have tried answers like this

**getSupportActionBar().hide();
before setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);**

but not sloved.how to solve?

Comment: Refer this link.its helps to solve your issue


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor

Answer (score 0):

When using `Toolbar` class with `AppCompat` v7 support library build v22+, you must use a parent theme with NoActionBar. For example, `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`