# Getting Error in Making Sliding Tabs Android app

Tags: android, pagerslidingtabstrip, android-tablayout

I am Creating Demo for Sliding Tabs in android .

After Adding all Requried java and Xml files, App is getting Crash.

[Link I referred](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html)

Using Above Link I created Demo.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Declaring Your View and Variables

    Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager pager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    SlidingTabLayout tabs;
    CharSequence Titles[]={"Home","Events"};
    int Numboftabs =2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
        adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

        // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

        // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
            }
        });

        // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);



    }
```

Error in Logcat

```
07-08 13:49:32.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7625): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-08 13:49:32.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7625): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.slidingtab/com.example.slidingtab.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.android4devs.slidingtab.SlidingTabLayout
    07-08 13:49:32.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7625):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
    07-08 13:49:32.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7625):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
    07-08 13:49:32.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7625):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
    07-08 13:49:32.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7625):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
```

help me to solve this Error.

Comment: do you have this class com.android4devs.slidingtab.SlidingTabLayout

Comment: ya iam having this class

Comment: in this specific package I mean if you go to your xml and press control and click on this line <com.android4devs.slidingtab.SlidingTabLayout would it navigate to this class or not ?

Comment: ya just now i changed my Package in xml , but again new error Coming

Comment: 07-08 14:02:57.715: E/AndroidRuntime(7934): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.slidingtab/com.example.slidingtab.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: Ok so it's another issue but the exception already provide you with the answer

Comment: ya iam getting  new Error in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for my Question

[Link i referred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26516817/4447803)

Add this line in Styles.xml

Styles.xml

```
<style name="NoActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

   </style>
```

In Manifest file Change your Theme Style as NoActionBarTheme

manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.slidingtab"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBarTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Tab1"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tab1" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Tab2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tab2" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

For your second error add this to your style.xml

```
<style >
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: in App Theme Or Any other?

Comment: in app theme add that line

Comment: post your style.xml please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor found answer from here Thank you

Comment: <style name="NoActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    
</style> it worked for me

Comment: glad you find the answer :)