# Splashscreen like google apps

Tags: android

Most of google applications (e.g Google Maps, Google sheets, etc...) have a pretty nice splashscreen, that pops up very quickly.

[image]

It doesn't look like a "classic" Android splashscreen made of an Activity launching another one after xx secs.

It makes me think of the iOS equivalent (Launch images).

Is it a new UI element that we can use ? Does somebody have an hint about that ?

Comment: use styles in splash instead of direct image in background.

Comment: Maybe, it's simply a custom Toast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a theme for your SplashActivity instead of directly setting the image in the layout.For eg:

```
<style name="Theme.Splash" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/ic_splash</item>
</style>
```

Then apply this theme to your splash activity in Manifest.for eg:

```
<activity
            android:name=".controller.activities.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Splash"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: @nios welcome .Do give it a try .that's the way i do it.

Comment: after adding this style in Main Activity. got this error "This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead"

Comment: @AbuNayemhave you tried this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26515159/3852907

Comment: When we migrate to the android navigation component, the application will have a single activity and splash fragment. Then how can we apply this style to splash fragment?