# This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor?

Tags: java, android, android-theme, android-toolbar

I am making an `Android` app using `Toolbar` with `Custom style` but when i'm running the app, i'm getting the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has
>   an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request
>   Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in
>   your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

**Styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>

</style>


<style name="MyEditTextTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Used for the bottom line when not selected / focused -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:endColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>




    <!-- colorControlActivated & colorControlHighlight use the colorAccent color by default -->
</style>

<style name="TabTextAppearance" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_information_category1);
    Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_information);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new TodayInformationFragment(), "Today");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThisWeekInformationFragment(), "This Week");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThisMonthInformationFragment(), "This Month");
    adapter.addFragment(new AllyearInformationFragment(), "All");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor)

Comment: Theme looks fine, did you point to it in the manifest?

Answer (score 23):

Clearly error says:

> This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor.
>   Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set
>   **windowActionBar to false** in your theme to use a Toolbar instead

**Use this in your Styles:**

```
 <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

**Updated:**

Android studio's default example is like this, take a look at the `AppTheme.NoActionBar`:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

**And in your `Manifest`:**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

And make sure your `Toolbar` implemented correctly.

For example, with `AppbarLayout`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarmain"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

Comment: I am trying this code but giving the same error Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: @BharatSindhav -  Use this in your manifest: `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"`

Answer (score 6):

Just go to your Manifest file and in the specific activity add

```xml
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case that happened because the phone was in dark mode and I didn't provide a dark mode for my app maybe. it works fine after disabling the dark mode.

Answer (score 0):

**in my case i was testing on mobile which was in dark theme i got this and the following code done work for me**

```
    <style name="Theme.QrCodeScanner" 
  parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

**set this in both themes.xm and themes.xml(night)**
**or if you want it for a specific activty then do the following in your manifest in specific activity**

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```