# application won't start but no errors in code

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, supportmapfragment

i have a tabbed layout application and the third tab has google maps implemented, no code errors but when i start in the emulator it doesn't even start it just states its been stopped

here is my main activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter =
            new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), MainActivity.this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    // Iterate over all tabs and set the custom view
    for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
        tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
    }
}

class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Home", "Shouts", "Maps", };
    Context context;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabTitles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new HomeFragment();
            case 1:
                return new ShoutsFragment();
            case 2:
                return new MapFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }

    public View getTabView(int position) {
        View tab = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.mapfragment, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) tab.findViewById(R.id.map);
        tv.setText(tabTitles[position]);
        return tab;
    }

    }
```

here is my activity main xml

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    app:tabTextColor="#d3d3d3"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#ff00ff"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is my map fragment class

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

MapView mMapView;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // inflate and return the layout
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapfragment, container,
            false);
    mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mMapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync((OnMapReadyCallback) this);
    // latitude and longitude
    double latitude = 17.385044;
    double longitude = 78.486671;

    // create marker
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
            new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps");

    // Changing marker icon
    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));



    // Perform any camera updates here
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mMapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mMapView.onLowMemory();
}
}
```

here is my fragment map xml file

```
<fragment
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:id="@+id/map"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
/>
```

here is my home fragment class

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get the view from fragment home.xml
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
    return view;

}
}
```

here is my home fragment xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/custom_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:singleLine="true"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

here is my shouts fragment class

```
public class ShoutsFragment extends Fragment{

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get the view from fragment home.xml
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shouts_fragment, container, false);
    return view;

}
}
```

here is my shouts xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/custom_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:singleLine="true"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

here is my logcat

```
03-25 11:06:59.012 3016-3016/com.example.hp_user.dn_tab1 I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
03-25 11:06:59.483 3016-3016/com.example.hp_user.dn_tab1 W/System:     ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.hp_user.dn_tab1-    2/lib/x86
03-25 11:06:59.669 3016-3016/com.example.hp_user.dn_tab1 I/GMPM: App                 measurement is starting up, version: 8487
03-25 11:06:59.669 3016-3016/com.example.hp_user.dn_tab1 I/GMPM: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
03-25 11:06:59.759 3016-3016/com.example.hp_user.dn_tab1 E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
03-25 11:06:59.813 3016-3016/com.example.hp_user.dn_tab1 E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
03-25 11:07:00.045 3016-3040/com.example.hp_user.dn_tab1 E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
03-25 11:07:00.379 3016-3016/com.example.hp_user.dn_tab1 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-25 11:07:00.381 3016-3016/com.example.hp_user.dn_tab1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.example.hp_user.dn_tab1, PID: 3016
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hp_user.dn_tab1/com.example.hp_user.dn_tab1.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:197)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
                                                                           at com.example.hp_user.dn_tab1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
03-25 11:07:08.761 3016-3022/com.example.hp_user.dn_tab1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 82.187ms
03-25 11:07:08.772 3016-3026/com.example.hp_user.dn_tab1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.588ms
03-25 11:07:20.033 3016-3022/com.example.hp_user.dn_tab1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 32.982ms
03-25 11:07:24.581 3016-3022/com.example.hp_user.dn_tab1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 91.462ms
03-25 11:07:32.640 3016-3022/com.example.hp_user.dn_tab1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 159.934ms
03-25 11:07:42.053 3016-3022/com.example.hp_user.dn_tab1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 50.217ms
03-25 11:07:47.886 3016-3022/com.example.hp_user.dn_tab1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10.813ms
03-25 11:07:50.622 3016-3022/com.example.hp_user.dn_tab1 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 331.902ms
```

Comment: post your logcat output

Comment: ive inserted it into the original question@Zielony

Comment: @AlexanderRufus First try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor add this line <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>  in your styles.xml

Comment: What is not clear in `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.`?

Answer (score 0):

Your logcat output tells you exactly what happened and how to fix it:

> This Activity already has
>   an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request
>   Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in
>   your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

I would bet on theme settings:

> Using the Toolbar to replace an ActionBar is pretty straight forward
>   and begins with making sure that the activity extends
>   ActionBarActivity. Also make sure that the theme for this activity is
>   a child of either Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar or
>   Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar. If you are not using the
>   Theme.AppCompat variants then you can alternatively add the following
>   lines to your theme:
>
> ```
> <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> 
> <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
> ```

See the full article here: http://mrengineer13.com/how-to-use-toolbar-to-replace-your-actionbar/

Comment: thank you but i can't see where that is set to true @Zielony

Comment: thank you very much, im only confused by the item name lines above where exactly are they supposed to go ?