# Caused by "java.lang.IllegalStateException" in play store crash report

Tags: java, android

Sorry for my english.
I got a problem with my first app. The app was works fine when I was running it from Android Studio. But when I uploaded it to play store some users reporting that "app crashing". Here is the logcat I got from play store,

````
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3530)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3682)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2144)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:223)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7750)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:612)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:997)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setSupportActionBar (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:575)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar (AppCompatActivity.java:183)
  at com.luxuryapps.maizbhandarigeeti2.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:41)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8012)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7996)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1309)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3503) ```
````

Comment: can you include the code of onCreate() of MainActivity? Especially the codes around line 41

Comment: Use crashlitycs in your app, it is very useful.

Comment: @ganjaam This is the line 41 ```setSupportActionBar(toolbar); ```

Comment: let me know if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37950046/8192914