# Some error when I try to run my application in android studio

Tags: android

I got some errors when I am trying to run my application ... ( I edit manifest a few days ago!)
I installed the lastest SDK files and it seems hasn't problem with SDK version...

errors in logcat:

[Click To show my errors picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyu42.jpg) 
[Click To show my errors picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRUAN.jpg)

and here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ir.homa">
<permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
</permission>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
    <application
        android:name=".AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



        <activity
            android:name=".HomaActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"   >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

UPDATE: 
my HomaActivity code:

```
    package ir.homa;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class HomaActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homa);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.homa, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show some code from the activity in question, `HomeActivity`. It seems that you're adding action bar twice.

Comment: I add it to question.. thank u

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor)

Comment: here is a suggestion: read the error?

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you're trying to add a toolbar:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

And it has already been supplied by window decor. It is all written in the error.
You can find your [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor). Which you could've googled out yourself also.