# getSupportActionBar(toolbar) throws null pointer exception using with Butterknife for toolbar

Tags: android, butterknife

I am using Butterknife to inject view  for the toolbar. But the method `getSupportActionBar(toolbar)` throws null pointer exception and the app unfortunately stopped. What can be done to solve this issue? I am using Android 4.2. So, is there any problem of using Butterknife with Jellybean?

**MainActivity**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.tool_bar_demo)
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @BindDrawable(R.drawable.backspace)
    Drawable backspace_btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("ABC");
    }
}
```

**activity_main**

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar_demo"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:titleTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**gradle**

```
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23

    apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'


    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
```

Comment: Why not just findViewById for your Toolbar>

Comment: I'm sure it's not related to Jellybean.

Comment: can you put some logs?

Comment: at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:130)
                                                                                    at example.materialtoolbarexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)

Comment: @Eenvincible I am using butterknife so, if there any better way to get the toolbar .

Comment: Hello @SatanPandeya , have you initialized toolbar  . i suppose you forgot to add toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);

Comment: please share your activity layout xml file

Comment: @ShresthaRohit At MainActivity: @BindView(R.id.tool_bar_demo)
    Toolbar toolbar;

Comment: @Eenvincible Plz find the xml layout file in my question. activity_main is also included.

Comment: @Amir  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{example.materialtoolbarexample/example.materialtoolbarexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: @SatanPandeya I think it's a problem with your style. you should use **NoActionBar** style.

Comment: <style name="YOUR_THEME" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

Comment: @Amir This time the code work and run without crashing but still throws    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{example.materialtoolbarexample/example.materialtoolbarexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead. Thanks for your advice and time . Is there is any way to avoid this ?

Comment: @SatanPandeya Can you post your Style ?

Comment: is a problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a issue with [Butterknife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife).

From the issue the main points collected are:

> > Butter Knife is just sugar on findViewById, and that's what is failing to find the view. As I said, make sure that layout is  in main_activity or ensure you put a Toolbar with that ID in main_activity layout.

**another comment says:**  if i set an id to my include like this :

```
<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/include4" />
```

That doesn't work. But if i remove the `android:id="@+id/include4"` it works. As of version 7.0.1, adding an ID to the include causes the view to not be found.

**The link to the issue:** [id issue of butterknife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/396)

Answer (score 1):

In fact it's not related to `Butterknife` or `Jellybean`. It's common exception that happen when you use ActionBar theme with `Toolbar`. And it's says you can't use `ActionBar` & `Toolbar` at the same time.

As I mention in comment you should change your style to following:

```
<style name="YOUR_STYLE" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
 .... other attrs here
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26515159/1462770) related thread to solve your issue.