# Add toolbar in android app

Tags: android-layout, listview, android-studio, android-fragments

I want to add toolbar in my android app but I am getting this error in my StudentDashboardActivity.java at run time after pushing my app on git. I could not find what's the problem behind of it.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.technerdshub.vusocial, PID: 31319
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.technerdshub.vusocial/com.technerdshub.vusocial.Activities.StudentDashboardActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
              at

              com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
              Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:198)
              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:130)
              at com.technerdshub.vusocial.Activities.StudentDashboardActivity.onCreate(StudentDashboardActivity.java:51)
              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
```

StudentDashboardActivity.java

```
package com.technerdshub.vusocial.Activities;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

    import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
    import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.technerdshub.vusocial.Fragments.TaskFragment;
    import com.technerdshub.vusocial.Fragments.dummy.DummyContent;
    import com.technerdshub.vusocial.R;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class StudentDashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private Toolbar toolbar;
        private TabLayout tabLayout;
        private ViewPager viewPager;
        /**
         * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
         * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
         */
        private GoogleApiClient client;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            displayLoginActivity();

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_dashboard);

    //        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
    //                        .applicationId("J5CIV2z6xeSCXDqdOfhE0kPSikvRFPyDyOJxqJNx")
    //                        .clientKey("bEWm4nWtWiBrMczGfOvA7s4Ulr2bAU3W3TtVSLDf")
    //                        .build()
    //        );
            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setElevation(2);


            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            setupViewPager(viewPager);

            tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    //        ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("Task");
    //        testObject.put("marks", 99);
    //        testObject.saveInBackground();

            // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
            // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
            client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
        }

        private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
            ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            adapter.addFragment(new TaskFragment(), "Quiz");
            adapter.addFragment(new TaskFragment(), "Assignment");
            adapter.addFragment(new TaskFragment(), "GDB");
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }



        private void displayLoginActivity() {

            Intent i = new Intent(this, Login.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
            // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
            client.connect();
            Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                    Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                    "StudentDashboard Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                    // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                    // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                    // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                    Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                    // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                    Uri.parse("android-app://com.technerdshub.vusocial.Activities/http/host/path")
            );
            AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();

            // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
            // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
            Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                    Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                    "StudentDashboard Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                    // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                    // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                    // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                    Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                    // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                    Uri.parse("android-app://com.technerdshub.vusocial.Activities/http/host/path")
            );
            AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
            client.disconnect();
        }

        class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
            private final List<TaskFragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
            private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

            public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
                super(manager);
            }

            @Override
            public TaskFragment getItem(int position) {
                return mFragmentList.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mFragmentList.size();
            }

            public void addFragment(TaskFragment fragment, String title) {
                mFragmentList.add(fragment);
                mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
            }


        }

    }
```

style.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>



    </style>

    <!--<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">-->
        <!--<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>-->
        <!--<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>-->



    <!--</style>-->

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="TEST" parent="AppTheme" >
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/com_facebook_blue</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/cardview_light_background</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/com_facebook_button_background_color_selected</item>
    </style>


    <!--&lt;!&ndash; new design fai&ndash;&gt;-->
    <!--<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">-->

    <!--</style>-->

    <!--<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">-->
        <!--<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>-->
        <!--<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>-->
        <!--<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>-->
        <!--<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>-->
        <!--<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>-->
    <!--</style>-->


</resources>
```

Please tell me, how can I resolve this error?

Comment: Please refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor

Comment: If you look at the error you can say it says at some point: "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead." which seems to be addressed by the linked question by the comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change style.xml to below given code

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the app Theme with windowActionBar as false in style.xml

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

if you have used any app support library for the theme need to include below line also

```
 <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Comment: I have already added these 2 lines in my style.xml