# android 5.1 using custom toolbar. App crash: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar

I am trying to make a common layout form my multiple activity . This commone layout is having drawer layout,custom toolbar and framelayout. The framelayout can be used to host any activity layout.

I am getting error while setting my toolbar i.e  setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

Error:

This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

I already tried setting following  but no luck
<"windowActionBar">false
<"windowNoTitle">true

drawer_toolbar_layout.xml

```
   <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:id="@+id/map_layout"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
          <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout"
            android:id="@+id/drawerlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <include
                    android:id="@+id/common_toolbar"
                    layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/framlay"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start" >
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:background="@drawable/shadow_rectangle"
                    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                    android:divider="@color/logoorange"
                    android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

activity java code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawer_toolbar_layout);
    FrameLayout mframeLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.framlay);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    View activityview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_usr_order_history, null);
    mframeLayout.addView(activityview);
    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.common_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

common_toolbar.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar   
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/toolbar_id"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:layout_margin="0dp"
      android:background="#2196f3"
      android:contentInsetLeft="10dp"
      android:contentInsetRight="10dp"
      android:contentInsetStart="10dp"
      android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:padding="0dp"
      app:contentInsetLeft="10dp"
      app:contentInsetRight="10dp"
      app:contentInsetStart="10dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_rl_incart"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_iv_cartimg"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_shopping_cart_black_24dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_tv_itemcnt"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_tv_orderhistory"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:textColor="@color/cb_errorRed"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow_button_rectangle"
            android:text="My Orders" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<--Styling theme code-->

<style name="AppTheme_NoAction" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item
</style>
```

**menifest.xml**

```
<activity> 
  android:name=".UsrOrderHistory_Activity"
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme_NoAction"
</activity>
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme_NoAction" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

With following lines commented the activity is working fine:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);  
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

At this time i dont know the consequences...

Comment: you are using a theme that already has action bar that is why you are getting exception

Comment: it is possible that you are adding it multiple times

Comment: can you show your import of `Toolbar` (get by `findViewById`)? is it [THIS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) class? I don't see it in any XML...

Comment: @Raju I didn't any "Toolbar" in your xml that's why you are getting this error !!! use <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar> as your action bar

Comment: @snachmsm ... import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar; is the import of toolbar.

Comment: @dex .. i have added the correct layout in the question..

Comment: The same code is working on android 4.4.4kt.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this?

"values/styles.xml, values-v11/styles.xml, and values-v14/styles.xml"

then you change value-v11/styles.xml and vlues-v14/styles.xml.

[This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31247031/6759520)

Comment: I have only values/styles.xml..Also the same code is workind on android 4.4.4kt

Comment: How about this? remove your code "app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" in common_toolbar.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your styles *res/values/styles* and change AppTheme's parent to 
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">` and then design you toolbar like this......

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
```

**EDIT**
Make sure that `setContentView(R.layout.drawer_toolbar_layout)` points to the layout which contains `common_toolbar`. Because in your layout, toolbar id is `toolbar_id`. Clean all your styling and just edit a `parent` theme.

Comment: Go to File -> Invalidate Cache / Restart and then Invalidate and Restart

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this line in your values/styles.xml file in main style tag:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
....
</style>
```

Comment: Please post your values/styles.xml file in the question