# BluetoothLeGatt implementation

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, manifest

I am trying to implement the BluetoothLeGatt Example Project from android into my own app to handle the BLE Services.

[BluetoothLeGatt Example Android](https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/index.html)

The actual state is that i have my own app which has only one activity and i am switching between the other pages with fragments. I would like to implement the android example so i can receive Bluetooth data and save it into a own data class (via an Interface or something like that not sure right now).

The Bluetooth Example is working without any Problems if i am running it on my device. I can also implement the example into my app and use it as "start activity" with the following manifest:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bb.app">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:debuggable="true">


        <activity
            android:name=".DeviceScanActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <!--android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"-->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
        <activity android:name=".DeviceControlActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".MyActivity"/>
        <service android:name=".BluetoothLeService" android:enabled="true"/>
        
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

But i am not able to Switch between the example activity and my own. I am using a simple Button with a onClickListener to Switch it like that:

```html
 buttonChangeActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChangeActivity);

        buttonChangeActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(DeviceControlActivity.this, "PRESSED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                try{
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(DeviceControlActivity.this, MyActivity.class);
                    DeviceControlActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(DeviceControlActivity.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

And it is still working. But then it says that the MyActivity class Needs to use the Theme.AppCompat but i am already using it. Here is the whole error code:

```html
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bb.app/com.example.bb.app.MyActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:343)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:312)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:277)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                        at com.example.bb.app.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:262)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
```

I am using a toolbar in my activity and the example Project uses an actionbar so i am pretty sure i Need to "Switch" between the themes while my Project is running but i don't know how to. I've already read some other cases about this behavior:

[Stackoverflow 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor)

Any advice how to Switch the themes while the Project is running or where to Change it in my Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Ok needed only few more minutes and i've fixed my own issue.

Just changed the manifest like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bb.app">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:debuggable="true">


        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <!--android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"-->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".DeviceControlActivity"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"/>
        <activity android:name=".DeviceScanActivity"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"/>
        <service android:name=".BluetoothLeService" android:enabled="true"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

So changing the theme for each activity, thanks anyways.