# Floating action button: Error inflating class FloatingActionButton

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, floating-action-button

I'm trying to use the floating action button in xamarin.forms from the NuGet `FAB.Forms` package([github](https://github.com/keannan5390/Xamarin.Plugin.FAB)). I tried to make my code like the example provided in the `Sample` folder

Xamarin.Droid `MainActivity.cs` file

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

    FAB.Droid.FloatingActionButtonRenderer.InitControl();

    LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

---

Xamarin.ios `AppDelegate.cs` file

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

    FAB.iOS.FloatingActionButtonRenderer.InitControl();

    LoadApplication(new App());

    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

---

Xamarin.portable `App.cs` file

```
public App(){MainPage = new LatestNews();}
```

---

LatestNews.xaml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:fab="clr-namespace:FAB.Forms;assembly=FAB.Forms"
             x:Class="HuraApp.Pages.LatestNews">
    ...
    <fab:FloatingActionButton
              x:Name="fabBtn"
              Source="plus.png"
              Size="Normal"
              Clicked="Handle_FabClicked"
              NormalColor="Green"
              RippleColor="Red" />
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

---

LatestNews.xaml.cs file

```
void Handle_FabClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.DisplayAlert("Floating Action Button", "You clicked the FAB!", "Awesome!");
}
```

---

portable packages.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="FAB.Forms" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="sameerIOTApps.Plugin.SecureStorage" version="1.2.1" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Xam.Plugin.Media" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.2.127" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms.Maps" version="2.3.2.127" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
</packages>
```

---

droid package.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="FAB.Forms" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.2.127" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms.Maps" version="2.3.2.127" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" version="29.0.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement" version="29.0.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps" version="29.0.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
</packages>
```

---

iOS package.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="FAB.Forms" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.2.127" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms.Maps" version="2.3.2.127" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
</packages>
```

---

But when I run the application on android emulator it gives me the error message

```
`Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`
```

Why is that happening? What am I missing? and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you use Activity extend MainActivity??

Comment: I'm coding in c# xamarin.forms not android. My (`Activities`/`Pages`) are extending `ContentPage`.

Comment: Ahh yess, On iOs it running without any problem?

Comment: I didn't run it on iOs yet. I'm now focusing on the droid part.

Comment: Please put your full class MainActivity.cs. and packages.config.

Comment: This is the only function existing in `MainActivity.cs`, there are no other functions or instances. I've updated my question to include the `package.config` files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem but i use Android. Just change the project parent theme     to any Theme.AppCompat~, this resolved my problem, maybe your also. And add `global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity` to your `MainActivity.cs`.

```
[Activity(Label = "YourName", , Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
        public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
        {
            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
            {
                base.OnCreate(bundle);

                global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

                FAB.Droid.FloatingActionButtonRenderer.InitControl();

                LoadApplication(new App());
            }
        }
```

You can add theme like this in `style.xml`

```
<style
        name="MyTheme"
        parent="Base.AppTheme">
</style>

<style name="Base.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
 <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
 <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Your code solved that error but gave me a NullReferenceException. I was able to solve the error from the two advices [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/39955/android-cant-use-theme). but solving that issue caused another error `Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.`.

Comment: (As usual)Thanks to this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26515159/4614264), I was able to solve my problem. I add `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item><item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>` inside my theme style. @mww I'd be glad to accept your answer as soon as you modify it to solve the errors I faced. Again, thanks :)