# How to change toolbar color on button click?

Tags: android

I have a app with a button and a Tool bar. I want to change the Tool bar color when button clicked.
I don't want to launch any other activity, I just want when user click button the color of my Toolbar get changes.

Comment: Show some code of what you've already tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

`getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent)));`

**UPDATE**

To change color of status bar you should add this code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
Window window = getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

Comment: That works but now the way that i want... I wanna post some images but its not allowing me. It's pretty hard to tell in words

Comment: Tell me your problem.

Comment: And accept the answer if it worked for you thank you!

Comment: See before clicking the button the toolbar is blue as primary color and dark blue is primary dark. When i click the button too l bar color changes but not the color of status bar at status bar its dark blue and at tool bar its pink.  I hope you understand my problem

Comment: I tried to accept your answer but its showing vote up by some who is lower 15 Reputation will get recorded. but not shown i n public don't know what the heck is this.

Comment: Just click on "wright" tick icon to accept my answer

Comment: Didn't you see wright tick just below upvote and downvote icon?

Comment: Bro 1 last question in window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLUE); } here is there any way to  use color which are in my resources instead of integer color ?

Comment: try this getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent) instead of Color.Blue

Answer (score 0):

Try This It will Work -

**In XML**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorControlActivated"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/but"
    android:text="ClickME" />
```

**In Java**

```
public class barTool extends AppCompatActivity {
Toolbar myToolbar;
Button myButton;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.toolbar);

    myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    myButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.but);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar); //Setting the Toolbar
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myToolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK); //Changing to Color to Black OnClick of Button
        }
    });
}}
```

and if error comes

**This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor**

Remove Previous Action Bar By Setting The below code in Styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item> <!--by setting last two the error is removed-->
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

This code is taken from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26515159/2156816).Please See this Link Also.