# Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR

Tags: android

I have a LoginActivityclass(TabActivity) which have following code to cover whole mobile screen

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplic
```

Now I want to go to another MainActivityclass(AppCompatActivity) using Intent which have toolbar. Its code is-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle  savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

XML-

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        app:contentInsetRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

It is working fine while I am not opening  MainClass using Intent, but I want t o open MainActivityClass there is an error -

This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request `Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR` and set `windowActionBar` to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.......

Comment: I want to open another activity class using  Intent from first one.

Comment: you have to Put your Theme code..also Manifest File...And this error is your Theme Error.

Comment: Post your Manifest file and you whole code of xml in which you have used Toolbar.

Comment: @NehaSharma  Possibly duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor

Comment: @NehaSharma edit your question with the above code..Don't just put your code in comment section no one is going to read that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this:

in manifest

```
// the activity where you want to show `toolbar`
    <activity android:name=".YourActivity"  
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"><!-- ADD THIS LINE -->
```

in styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

add this `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"` to your application tag in the Manifest file

```
<application
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
</application>
```

Comment: it will work with intent too...intent will start your activity..so the manifest will always be called

Comment: yaah.. this answer change the error to- You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs by many mistakes 
I have listed below some Situations :

1.) If you have not created Toolbar in your layout

2.) If you are using

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

Theme and try to get Actionbar.

3) if you have not

```
extends AppCompatActivity
```