# Error when trying to extend as BaseActivity

Tags: android

I am trying to create a Nav Drawer Activity as a Base Activity. I did something like below.

When i ran it, I got below error.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main   Process:
>   com.bugmanagement.pankaj.androidexample, PID: 2297
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.bugmanagement.pankaj.androidexample/com.bugmanagement.pankaj.androidexample.Activities.UserManagement.Auth.LoginActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action
>   bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request
>   Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in
>   your theme to use a Toolbar instead.    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)       at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has
>   an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request
>   Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in
>   your theme to use a Toolbar instead.    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:199)
>       at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:133)
>       at
>   com.bugmanagement.pankaj.androidexample.Activities.UserManagement.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:31)
>       at
>   com.bugmanagement.pankaj.androidexample.Activities.UserManagement.Auth.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:30)
>       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)       at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)       at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

**style.xml is below**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

**styles.xml(v21)**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**Base Activity**

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.base, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue :

> This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

You are using a theme with action bar and at the same time in your xml a Toolbar is use and set like actionbar.

Change the parent of your AppTheme with  a theme without actionbar for exemple in your style.xml :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >
   <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
   <!-- your item here -->
</style>
```

EDIT:

For the nav icon

in your activity be sure to have somethong like that:

```
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_closed);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        //your code
    }


    @Override
    public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: The nav drawer doesn't open or there is not the nav icon ?

Comment: Yes and no , a theme with action bar handle the nav icon by itself , a theme without action bar but with a toolbar, you need to set the fav icon like in the code above.

Comment: Can you share your XML with nav drawer and your oncreate method please ?

Comment: In base activity code, there are missing after `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`, these lines `getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

This is the same for on `onPostCreate` and `onConfigurationChanged` functions, please compare with my suggestion and add these missing part. 

Let me know if it is helpful :)

Comment: I am still facing the same problem. Do u prefer coming over team Viewer? or could I email you code?

Answer (score 0):

> Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set
>   windowActionBar to false in your theme

Here is the origin of your problem , and it is happened because you set `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
 <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>`

in the activity you are setting toolbar as a actionBar
`Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

remove this line `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>` from your style.xml file

you can use this piece of code for no action bar theme styling . add this code in your style file

```
<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/primary</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/iron</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/iron</item>

    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/primary_darker</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/primary_darker</item>

    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
</style>
```

Comment: making base activity abstract or not  isn't the issue for this problem you have asked !!! @Pankaj

Comment: I still facing same issue.

Comment: one think did you add theme attribute for your base activity in your manifest file . can you share your manifest file code . maybe you accidentally didn't add theme for your baseactivity @pankaj