# firebase login register app crash

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a login register kinda app using Firebase on Android Studio. It builds just fine, but when I run it on my phone, the launcher activity works but the problem occurs when I use my button to access my Firebase login activity. My logcat is given below with my launcher activity code and login activity code. How do I resolve the exceptions and stack traces in my logcat?

My login activity:

```
    package com.delaroystudios.database;

        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
        import android.text.TextUtils;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.ProgressBar;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
        import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
        import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
        import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class Teacher extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Button btnSignup, btnLogin, btnReset;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Teacher.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        // set the view now
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        btnSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Teacher.this, SignupActivity.class));
            }
        });

        btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Teacher.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
            }
        });

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //authenticate user
                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(Teacher.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // there was an error
                                    if (password.length() < 6) {
                                        inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(Teacher.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Teacher.this, Login.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My launcher activity:

```
  package com.delaroystudios.database;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        final Button bstudent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bstudent);
        final Button bteacher = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bteacher);

        bstudent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent stuintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Student.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(stuintent);
            }
        });


        bteacher.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent teaintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Teacher.class);
               MainActivity.this.startActivity(teaintent);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

MY logcat after the app crash:

```
06-26 20:38:31.327 18100-18100/com.delaroystudios.database E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.delaroystudios.database, PID: 18100
 Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.ngocgiap.hightlifelight, iconPack:com.ngocgiap.hightlifelight, fontPkg:com.ngocgiap.hightlifelight, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.ngocgiap.hightlifelight, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.ngocgiap.hightlifelight}
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.delaroystudios.database/com.delaroystudios.database.Teacher}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:207)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:130)
     at com.delaroystudios.database.Teacher.onCreate(Teacher.java:44)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: in the teacher login activity you are unnecessarily providing action bar. Make sure that in the theme of your Teacher activity  in styles.xml, you have added NoActionBar style

Comment: the error is with the style in the app
follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor