# Navigation Drawable

Tags: android-layout

I have Error:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.kangive.kangive, PID: 4855
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kangive.kangive/com.kangive.kangive.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity

What I can do? I have added an activity for the navigation drawable and I have this error, I am a beginner.
Greetings.

Comment: maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/26515159/2940733

Answer (score 0):

Insert in Manifest.xml

```
<activity 
android:name=".activity.YourActivity" 
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

Inser styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">

<item name="windowActionBar">false</item> 
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```