# After adding recycler and cardview dependecy, the app crashes

Tags: android

when I add the dependency in app gradle for recycler view and card view the app starts giving below error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: com.example.pawadube.helloworld, PID: 3549
>                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pawadube.helloworld/com.example.pawadube.helloworld.ApplicationActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

My gradle file is as below:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pawadube.helloworld"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
}
```

MainActivity class

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Credentials;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etServerURL, etUsername, etPassword;
    Button buttonConnect;
    ProgressDialog progressDoalog;
    String serverURL, username, password;
    String loginURL = "/rest/allData/index";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        findId();

        buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                loginButtonClicked(view);
            }
        });
    }

    void loginButtonClicked(View view) {
        progressDoalog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        progressDoalog.setTitle("Connecting...");
        progressDoalog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDoalog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

        boolean flag = validateField();
        if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Please check internet connectvity.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
            TextView tv = (TextView) snackBarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
            snackbar.show();
        } else if (flag == true) {
            String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
            String url = etServerURL.getText().toString() + loginURL;
            new LoginServerTest(view).execute(username, password, url);
        } else {
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Please fill all the details.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
            snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            TextView tv = (TextView) snackBarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            snackbar.show();
        }
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }

    void findId() {
        etServerURL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.serverURL);
        etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        buttonConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
    }

    boolean validateField() {
        boolean flag = true;
        serverURL = etServerURL.getText().toString().trim();
        username = etUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if (serverURL.equals("")) {
            etServerURL.setError("Server address is mandatory.");
            etServerURL.requestFocus();
            flag = false;
        } else if (username.contentEquals("")) {
            etUsername.setError("Username is mandatory.");
            etUsername.requestFocus();
            flag = false;
        } else if (password.contentEquals("")) {
            etPassword.setError("Password is mandatory.");
            etPassword.requestFocus();
            flag = false;
        } else if (!URLUtil.isValidUrl(serverURL)) {
            etServerURL.setError("Entered server address is invalid");
            etServerURL.requestFocus();
            flag = false;
        }
        return flag;
    }

    void clearFields() {
        etServerURL.setText("");
        etUsername.setText("");
        etPassword.setText("");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (progressDoalog != null) {
            progressDoalog.dismiss();
            progressDoalog = null;
        }
    }

    class LoginServerTest extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String[]> {

        private View rootView;
        public LoginServerTest(View rootView) {
            this.rootView = rootView;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDoalog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String username = strings[0];
            String password = strings[1];
            String url = strings[2];

            String credential = Credentials.basic(username, password);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .get()
                    .addHeader("authorization", credential)
                    .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
                    .build();

            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String body = response.body().string();
                    String code = response.code() + "";
                    String[] output = {code, body};
                    return output;
                } else {
                    String body = "Error: 404";
                    String code = response.code() + "";
                    String[] output = {code, body};
                    return output;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] strings) {
            super.onPostExecute(strings);
            progressDoalog.dismiss();
            if (strings != null) {
                if (strings[0].contentEquals("200")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, TabActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged in successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    clearFields();
                } else if (strings[0].contentEquals("401")) {
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "Username/password is invalid, please try again.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
                    snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                    TextView tv = (TextView) snackBarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    snackbar.show();
                } else if (strings[0].contentEquals("404")) {
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, strings[1] + ", please check the server URL.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
                    snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                    TextView tv = (TextView) snackBarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    snackbar.show();
                } else {
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, strings[0] + " please try again.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
                    snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                    TextView tv = (TextView) snackBarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    snackbar.show();
                }
            } else {
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "Oops something went wrong, please check the server address.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
                snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                TextView tv = (TextView) snackBarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                snackbar.show();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Styles.xml file

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="EditText">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextView">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Tab">
        <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

Comment: the solution to your problem is here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor

Comment: That is not the reason for the crash, it is a toolbar vs theme problem!

Comment: can you share the activity class? Looks like problem is on activity class

Comment: Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: please follow this answer it will solve your problem <br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor

Comment: As an aside, it's a good idea to specify exactly the same version for all of the Android support libraries used in a project. You have 27.0.2, 26.1.0, 26.0.0 and whatever `+` resolves to. While this may not have anything to do with the issue at hand, it can cause other issues, so I figured I'd chip in with it.

Comment: I've added the activity class. I tried other solutions given but no luck.

Comment: when I tried commenting the below code related to tool bar it works
//        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
however it looks weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Sharing your styles.xml file.

if it having this :

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

than just change to :

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

and keep all the other lines sames as usual.

Comment: added the styles.xml file

Comment: can you  try my answer of replacing the first line?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the older version, It worked for me:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

Comment: Nice guess @Sinan but according to the crash logs of the question, the cause is a toolbar and theme!