# My app crashes after a button is clicked

Tags: android, android-activity

When I press a button on the main menu of my app to launch a new activity, the whole app crashes and I am not too sure why. It is the efficiency activity. These two files are called the `activity_efficiency.xml` and the `Efficiency.java` class.

```
public void goEfficient(View v){
    if(v.getId()==R.id.efficiencyID){
        Intent goefficient = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Efficiency.class);
        startActivity(goefficient);
    }
}
```

the snippet above, it what is called from the main activity. This works fine, its the next section of the activity which causes it to crash I believe:

```
package com.laminar.calculator.calculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Efficiency extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_efficiency);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}
public void workout(View a){
    EditText EO = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.energyoutput);
    EditText EI = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.energyinput);
    TextView VIEW = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView15);

    if(EO.length()==0||EI.length()==0){
        Snackbar.make(a, "Please enter your values into the equation", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }else{

        double oe = Double.parseDouble(EO.getText().toString());
        double ei = Double.parseDouble(EI.getText().toString());
        double stage1 = oe / ei;
        double stage2 = stage1 * 100;

        VIEW.setText("Efficiency: "+stage2+"J");
    }
}

}
```

And then, this is the `activity.efficiency.xml` text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Efficiency">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Work out the efficiency of an object"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium" 
/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/energyoutput"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter useful energy output here (J)"
    android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/energyinput"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter input energy here (J)"
    android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/workout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Calculate" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium" 
/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView11"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="87dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/efficiency2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Just to clarify, every other activity in my app loads up fine. The complete code for my app can be found on my GitHub here: [My Remote Repository](https://github.com/Patalayus/CalculatorApp/tree/master/app/src/main)

Heres the Run Log on the crash:

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3046)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:207)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:130)
                  at com.laminar.calculator.calculator.Efficiency.onCreate(Efficiency.java:18)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6998)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1230)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2899)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3046) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

If any extra information is needed to fix this problem, please do not hesitate to leave a comment.

Comment: Add the crash logs .

Comment: no need to host your log error out there...post it here

Comment: Look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor

Comment: my bad, I'll fix that

Comment: What does your manifest look like?

Comment: I can't see any toolbar in `xml`

Comment: Well now that I've removed the two lines which address the toolbar in Efficiency.java, the activity launches without any issues

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to get rid of the secondary Toolbar which I had created.
I was trying to add a second toolbar to the activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_efficiency);
    //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}
```

Answer (score -3):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action
>   bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request
>   Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in
>   your theme to use a Toolbar instead

Looks like you're trying to set an action bar for an activity that already has one. Do what the log says and set `windowActionBar` to `false` in your `styles.xml` (or whatever it's called) file, like so:

`res/values/styles.xml` (redacted):

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- ... -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

That should allow you to use your own.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that's it