# Use of AsyncTask in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to write a Fibonacci application using AsyncTask in Android Studio. Although there is no error in my app, when I run it it says: "MyApplication has stopped!". Can anyone point out my mistakes?
I have included the java code here.
Thanks in advance.

```
package com.example.asus.myapplication;

public class fibonacci
        extends AppCompatActivity
        implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button SolveButton;
    private EditText Number;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fibonacci);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Number.setOnClickListener(this);
        SolveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        SolveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button: {
                double i =
                        Double.parseDouble(Number.getText().toString());
                new fibonacci_thread().execute(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    public class fibonacci_thread
            extends AsyncTask<Double, Void,
            Double> {
        double s1 = 0;
        double s2 = 1;
        double s3 = 0;

        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(Double... params) {

            for(double k = 3; k <= params[0]; k++) {
                s3 = s1 + s2;
                s1 = s2;
                s2 = s3;
            }

            return s2;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Double result) {
            EditText textView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            String yourDoubleString = String.valueOf("Result: " +
                                                             result);
            textView.setText(yourDoubleString);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my Event Log during installation of the app on a "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280", using Genymotion:
12:14 AM    Genymotion: Device [Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280]: started

12:15 AM    Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

12:15 AM    Gradle build finished in 6s 61ms

12:15 AM    Instant Run performed a full build and install since
                the installation on the device does not match the local build on disk.
                (Don't show again)

12:15 AM    Can't bind to local 8623 for debugger

Comment: Show the logcat with the exception which lets your app crash.

Comment: Please update your question and add the `Log`.

Comment: `have one button for execution` Ok. But when does your app crash?

Comment: `String.valueOf("Result: " + 
      result);` ??? That does not look good. You could as well use `"Result: " + 
      result;`

Comment: just give me your monitor or Logcat log

Comment: What is `setContentView(R.layout.content_fibonacci);` and why does it exist?

Comment: You should not have two `setContentView` method calls

Comment: I removed the second setContentView and my problem still exists. I updated my question above and added the log file.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting `IllegalStateException` that leads to a `RuntimeException` in this case because you are programmatically adding toolbar in your view, while your activity might have decor provided action bar. From here on wards you can apply two approaches:

1. Use the default action bar and remove the following two lines from your code:

   `Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`
2. First remove the default action bar and then use your own toolbar in its place. You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor) for details.

Comment: I checked my styles.xml and I have got this two lines:                                       
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>                                        So I suppose my problem in installation is not related to the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

After disabling Instant Run from settings, my problem was solved! This way I could install the App on my devices. Thank you buddies for your helps!