# How to inflate menu on actionbar on the left

Tags: android, kotlin, android-actionbar

I have a menu inside the top actionbar that allows for changing a password, editing their profile, and logging out.  What I need is, once they click the "edit bio" option, I want to add an arrow or a "<" to the actionbar on the left side to allow the user a "go back" option if they want to exit editing the profile as well as hiding the right side menu option while they are editing.  Here's my code for inflating the menu on the right:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?, inflater: MenuInflater?) {
        inflater!!.inflate(R.menu.profiletoolbar, menu)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }

    //get the actionbar selction when pressed
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean = when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.userLogout -> {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
            val i = Intent(context, Login::class.java)
            startActivity(i)
            true
        }
        R.id.editBio -> {
            editProfileBio()
            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

I really want to understand what the process is behind how this works.  Can someone help me?  I'd also be okay with just replacing the menu on the right with an arrow or a "<" as well, although I don't like that idea as much.

Answer (score 0):

How about this: `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()`

```
R.id.editBio -> {
            editProfileBio()
            supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
            true
        }
```

To handle when pressed:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        // do your stuff when pressed the back Button
    }
```

---

> I'd also be okay with just replacing the menu on the right with an
>   arrow or a "<" as well, although **I don't like that idea as much**.

Don't like that idea either. By enabling back `Button` when `editbio` clicked, you'll have access to the current menu and there will be a back `Button` too so this seems to be the perfect way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to listen for the R.id.home option

1. Add a toolbar to activity layout.
2. In your fragment declare that it needs to redraw the toolbar.

   [setHasOptionsMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean))(true);
3. Set toolbar as action bar

   ```
   private fun setActionBar() {
       val toolbar = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tb_main_toolbar)

       if (toolbar != null) {
           (getActivity() as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
       }
       val actionBar = (getActivity() as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar
       if (null != actionBar) {
           customizeActionBar(actionBar)
       }
   }

   private fun customizeActionBar(actionBar: ActionBar) {
       actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
       actionBar.setTitle(R.string.logout)
       actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
       actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
       actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.logout)
   }
   ```
4. Override onOptionItemSelected and do your functionality

   ```
   override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
       when (item.itemId) {
           android.R.id.home ->  
               FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
               val i = Intent(context, Login::class.java)
               startActivity(i)
               true
       }
       return true
   }
   ```

Comment: I tried implementing this and I get unresolved references on `setSupportActionBar` and `actionBar`.  I didn't mention that this is inside a fragment if that makes a difference.  Also I do have `lateinit var toolbar: ActionBar`.

Comment: I have updated the answer for fragment scenario please check

Comment: What is `tb_main_toolbar`?  Is that a menu layout item?

Comment: It is the id of the toolbar which is present in the layout file of activity

Comment: I am getting this error: `This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.`

Comment: Ok, Use AppCompatActivity and for this issue you should see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26515159/6393514