# Activity intent to Navigation Drawer Activity (App Crashes)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, navigation-drawer

My application crashes after the activity is being intent on the navigation drawer which is the main activity...Could someone help me please...

Below is my code for Introduction.java

```
public class Introduction extends AppCompatActivity{

    //POP UPS
    ImageView getstart;

    //image button
    MediaPlayer background_music;
    int length;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.introduction);
        bmusic();
        getstart=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.playnow);
        final MediaPlayer button= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.intro_button);
        getstart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                button.start();
                new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Intent goMain= new Intent(Introduction.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(goMain);
                        finish();
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }


        });


    }

    public void bmusic() {
        background_music = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.intro_adventure);
        background_music.setLooping(true);
        background_music.start();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        background_music.pause();
        length = background_music.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestart();
       background_music.seekTo(length);
        background_music.start();
    }


}
```

And here is my code in MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private DrawerLayout drawer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open
                , R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new fragment_home()).commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.nav_home:

                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new fragment_home()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_tips:

                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new fragment_tips()).commit();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_about:

                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new fragment_about()).commit();
                break;


            case R.id.share:

                Toast.makeText(this, "Share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.rate:

                Toast.makeText(this, "Rate this app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error on  my logcat

```
E/HW-JPEG-DEC: [HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete](3321): HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
E/HW-JPEG-DEC: [HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete](3321): HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.james.navigate, PID: 4947
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.james.navigate/com.james.navigate.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2793)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:201)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
                      at com.james.navigate.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6915)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2746)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Comment: We need the stacktrace.

Comment: Just edited my post...sorry for the delay

Comment: That's not a stacktrace.

Comment: GravityCompat.START is the point

Comment: @HassanBadawi [huh](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#closeDrawer(int))?

Comment: is this the one sir? My apologies for I am new In android development

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor)

Comment: @James1234 : Welcome to SO. Add this to your styles: `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>` or just use a parent without `ActionBar` in your styles: `parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"`

Comment: thank you sir @Mohsen it worked

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your styles has an `ActionBar` and in your java codes, you declared the `Toolbar`.

So, add this to your `styles.xml`:

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

<sub>This will tell that this theme doesn't have `ActionBar` but you can declare `Toolbar` in java side</sub>

Or just use a parent **without** `ActionBar`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

The second one is the easiest way to do that.

**Update:** for AndroidX or up to 28 API:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: Remember to use `Theme.MaterialComponents` **If** you migrated to `AndroidX` or you used material dependency. This might cause some issues and crash would happen.