# App Crashes After The Splash Screen Is Loaded

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, crash

**As soon as I am launching my application , the splash screen appears but after 4 seconds the app crashes , I don't know what is the problem . I have already tried and tested other solutions but nothing worked for me. If any of you could tell me the solution then it would be of great help.**

Splash.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import com.example.myapplication.MainActivity;
import com.example.myapplication.R;

public class Splash extends MainActivity {
public static int splashTimeout=2000;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent=new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        } ,splashTimeout );
    }
}
```

activity_splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/java_bg2"
    tools:context=".Splash">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="203dp"
        android:layout_height="172dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="136dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/java_bg1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/java_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="376dp"
        android:layout_height="77dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/courgette"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/black"
        android:shadowColor="@color/black"

        android:text="@string/software_sucks_because_users_demand_it_to"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.457"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.84" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.example.myapplication.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);

        binding.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Thoda Wait Kar Na Bhai", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }

    private void activity3() {
        System.out.println("Activity3");
    }

    private void activity2() {
        System.out.println("Activity2");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.MyApplication.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType = "centerCrop"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/include"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/background" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />



</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
        <activity android:name=".decToHex"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".decToOct" />
        <activity android:name=".decToBin" />
        <activity android:name=".binToHex" />
        <activity android:name=".binToOct" />
        <activity android:name=".binToDec" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat

```
2021-06-28 17:41:29.470 6195-6195/com.example.myapplication I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2021-06-28 17:41:29.493 6195-6195/com.example.myapplication W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2021-06-28 17:41:30.696 6195-6273/com.example.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
2021-06-28 17:41:30.758 6195-6273/com.example.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2021-06-28 17:41:30.758 6195-6273/com.example.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2021-06-28 17:41:30.758 6195-6273/com.example.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2021-06-28 17:41:30.759 6195-6273/com.example.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2021-06-28 17:41:30.789 6195-6273/com.example.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xac8b1e60: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2021-06-28 17:41:30.802 6195-6273/com.example.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xac8b1e60: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xac88b280)
2021-06-28 17:41:30.858 6195-6273/com.example.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xac8b1e60: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xac88b280)
2021-06-28 17:41:32.770 6195-6204/com.example.myapplication I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=30KB
2021-06-28 17:41:32.772 6195-6204/com.example.myapplication I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=29KB, data=30KB
2021-06-28 17:41:32.772 6195-6204/com.example.myapplication I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
2021-06-28 17:41:32.806 6195-6195/com.example.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-06-28 17:41:32.808 6195-6195/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 6195
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:575)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:183)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Have you read the stack trace? I presume your theme *isn't* a `NoActionBar` theme and then you're trying to set another one with your `Toolbar`. So you can either do what it tells you to, or use a `NoActionBar` theme if you're using an app compat or material theme.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set action bar with activity twice. remove below line from code or if you do not want to remove below line disable default action bar from activity using theme.

```
setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Your logs has your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line

```
 <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

to your theme declaration inside of your app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml.

Also, if you're using AppCompatActivity support library of version 22.1 or greater, add this line:

```
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Your theme declaration may look like this after all these additions:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```