# AppCompat 22.1.0 Theme Runtime Exception

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-theme, android-appcompat, android-styles

After updated the Android Support Library to 22.1, I've been experience some crashes regarding the current theme features. The exception looks like this...

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{....}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features
```

In my theme XML, I'm getting a "Can't resolve parent" here at parent="@style/Theme... etc.

```
<style name="FestThemeBase" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Fest.ActionBar.Solid</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/Widget.Fest.ActionBar.TabTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/empty</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/main_fest_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/main_fest_color</item>
```

I tried to do what was suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790070/upgraded-to-appcompat-v22-1-0-and-now-getting-illegalargumentexception-appcompa), but am still getting the same exception at runtime.

Has anyone else experienced this / know if there's a quick fix to this problem?