# Error showing at onCreate() while using AppCompactActivity

Tags: android, eclipse

I updated my SDK to 22(Android 5.1.1).
Then I used AppCompactActivity instead of Activity.
Here is the logcat output.

```
04-23 13:51:40.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3150): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11
04-23 13:51:40.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:77)
04-23 13:51:40.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:414)
04-23 13:51:40.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:57)
04-23 13:51:40.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):     at com.emapps.easystudy.StartActivity.onCreate(StartActivity.java:61)
04-23 13:51:40.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
04-23 13:51:40.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
04-23 13:51:40.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
04-23 13:51:40.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
04-23 13:51:40.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
04-23 13:51:40.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
04-23 13:51:40.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-23 13:51:40.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
04-23 13:51:40.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
04-23 13:51:40.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 13:51:40.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-23 13:51:40.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
04-23 13:51:40.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
04-23 13:51:40.524: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I'm now using eclipse,Sir .

Comment: Have you used Theme.appcompat in your style???

Comment: Yes , I've used  @style/theme.appcompact in AndroidManifest.xml
Like this :android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"

Answer (score 1):

I tried this:

a) Restarted eclipse.

b) Deleted all .jar files under libs/ folder. (If you have android-support-v4.jar or any other lib files)

c) Also, checked at [Chris Banes's Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790070/upgraded-to-appcompat-v22-1-0-and-now-getting-illegalargumentexception-appcompa)

d) Clean build

Comment: What is your target device android release version? 5.0?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, 
and update all support library to the latest version (include android-support-v13.jar). It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by:

> right click android progect ---> Android tools ---> add support
>   liberary...--->download latest android support