# java.lang.VerifyError: When Using AppcompactActivity

Tags: android, appcompatactivity

i created a dummy activity and i am trying to deeplink my dummy activity ,

my manifest

```
  <activity android:name="com.eminosoft.ebookread.activity.DummyActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
            <data android:host="dashboard" android:scheme="wowioapp"></data>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>/>
```

my DummyActivity

```
public class DummyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dummy_activity);
    Button btnSplashScreen=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_goSplashScreen);
    btnSplashScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(DummyActivity.this,SplashScreenActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

but i am getting following error at oncreate

```
  12-19 12:52:48.061 7239-7239/com.wowio.ebookreader E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.wowio.ebookreader, PID: 7239
                                                                 java.lang.VerifyError: android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV9
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:205)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:525)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:74)
                                                                     at com.eminosoft.ebookread.activity.DummyActivity.onCreate(DummyActivity.java:20)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5363)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
                                                                     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

but if i Extend my dummyActivity with **Activity** instead of **AppCompactActivity** its working fine , why is AppCompactActivity giving this error?

i already refered [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816687/error-showing-at-oncreate-while-using-appcompactactivity) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668788/android-java-lang-verifyerror)

Thank you

Comment: provide manifest of SplashScreen activity