# AppCompat does not support the current theme features PRE L

Tags: android

i get AppCompat does not support the current theme features
on any pre l device works well on L however already added WindowNoTitle stuff

Comment: I don't understand at all what you are asking for/trying to fix

Comment: sorry for the lack of information provided, application crashed with the  message "AppCompat does not support the current theme features"  on pre Lollipop devices this was fixed by adding <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item> into styles

Comment: Check this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790070/upgraded-to-appcompat-v22-1-0-and-now-getting-illegalargumentexception-appcompa

Answer (score 0):

You need to direct inheritance Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar