# ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout$LayoutParams

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-appcompat

I have converted my Eclipse Project into Android Studio project and when i run the app i get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout$LayoutParams
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.applyInsets(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:172)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:317)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My theme is:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat" />

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
</style>
```

My Activity is extending `AppCompactActivity` and its layout is:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <!-- Your normal content view -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <!-- <include layout="@layout/toolbar" /> -->

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frag_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

                <!-- The navigation drawer -->

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/toolbar_shadow" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Your drawer view. This can be any view, LinearLayout -->
    <!-- is just an example. As we have set fitSystemWindows=true -->
    <!-- this will be displayed under the status bar. -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_view"
        android:layout_width="304dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <!-- Your drawer content -->

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            style="@style/NavDrawer"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/icons"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/divider"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/drawer_listview_background_selector" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Please note that i have included following items in the theme after reading the [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29790071/1773155)

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

The project has following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.+@aar'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext:library:0.0.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.flavienlaurent.datetimepicker:library:0.0.2'
    compile('com.mikepenz.materialdrawer:library:2.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.+@aar'
    compile 'com.github.alamkanak:android-week-view:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.johnkil.android-robototextview:robototextview:2.4.0'
    // AboutLibraries Library
    compile('com.mikepenz.aboutlibraries:library:4.7.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    // ChangeLog Libraries
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.changeloglib:library:1.5.2'
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3-with-sources.jar')
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.twotoasters.SectionCursorAdapter:library:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.3@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using CyanogenMod?

Comment: @ChrisBanes No, i am testing on GenyMotion Emulator.

Comment: Also the project is working if i run it from Eclipse IDE.

Comment: I tried it on Android Device running 4.4.4, the app is crashing there too.

Comment: I think that you have the MaterialDesign from com.github.navasmdc, maybe at the time to do the import to android studio , he misunderstood the references and mix them

Comment: @ChrisBanes, why did you ask if this was CyanogenMod? I am facing a similar problem and it happens to be on a device running cyanogen mod 11.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same kind of issue, I changed my style to following and that solved.

Before

```
    <style name="ImageViewer" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
       <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
       <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
       <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
   </style>
```

After

```
    <style name="ImageViewer" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
       <!--<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>-->
       <!--<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>-->
       <!--<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>-->
   </style>
```

And my NoActionBar theme is

```
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
       <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
       <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
   </style>
```