# App Compat does not support current theme feature?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I am developing an android app using android sdk 5.1 api 22.I am trying to implement the material design in my app. For that purpose i have created some xml & java files.I have set the style in style.xml but when i run the app i get error as

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features
```

I have followed some tutorials for this

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base"></style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.search_bar) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29790071/115145

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upgraded to AppCompat v22.1.0 and now getting IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790070/upgraded-to-appcompat-v22-1-0-and-now-getting-illegalargumentexception-appcompa)

Comment: No working for me@shkschneider

Comment: Me too. 
I have deleted android support lib and reintall but I cannot fixed it.