# Which is the style when I use this com.android.support:design:22.2.0

Tags: android

When I use

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

I don't know which is the style because I remove

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

So I have to use other style

```
resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

</style>
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still using `AppCompatActivity`, or its `ActionBarActivity` predecessor, you still use `Theme.AppCompat` (or themes that inherit from it) as before. `design` pulls in `appcompat-v7` automatically as a transitive dependency.

Comment: I'm using AppcompatActivity. My problem is thisjava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features

Comment: @Cabezas: You would get the same error from using `appcompat-v7` directly. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790070/upgraded-to-appcompat-v22-1-0-and-now-getting-illegalargumentexception-appcompa

Comment: This is my solution <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"> Thanks, CommonsWare.