# Android Support Design gradle error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat, android-support-design

This was my `build.gradle` file:

```
...
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    ...
}
```

before I add:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Now when I build or rebuild my project (I've synced `gradle` a few times) I get this errors:

```
.../utils/CustomEditText.java
Error:(6, 42) Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class TintEditText
Error:(14, 35) Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class TintEditText
Error:(37, 8) Gradle: error: cannot find symbol method isInEditMode()
Error:(57, 3) Gradle: error: cannot find symbol method setTypeface(Typeface)
Error:(65, 5) Gradle: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(67, 23) Gradle: error: cannot find symbol variable super
...
```

Inside my `CustomEditText` (that extends `TintEditText`) and inside all Activities that use that `CustomEditText`.

The import doesn't throw any error nor the `Class:`

```
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintEditText;
```

What could it be?

**UPDATE:**
Using **ianhanniballake** suggestion, `AppCompatEditText` instead of the internal `TintEditText`, solves the compile time error and answers this question but now I'm having a run time error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features
```

I've seen some question related to this and the solution mentioned was something like:

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        ...
</style>
```

But I don't want to fallow this approach because I've some `Activities` that use `ActionBar` and others who don't. My styles are:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/txt_light_grey</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/default_orange</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/txt_light_grey</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.Orange" parent="MyTheme">
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/default_orange</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.FullScreen" parent="MyTheme">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

And inside my base `Activity` I do:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(mActionBarView != null ? Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR : Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

To enable or disable the `ActionBar`.
As I've stated this works pretty well until I add `'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'` or update `appcompat-v7:22.0.0` to 22.**2**.0. I just want to use a `TabLayout`, but I guess I'll not...

Comment: I got this error too after updating to latest android design library..I just changed to Edittext.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of version [AppCompat 22.1.0](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html), you should use [AppCompatEditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatEditText.html) instead of the internal `TintEditText`.

Comment: What is the difference between AppcompatEdittext and the normal Edittext..I could not see any difference between them

Comment: @Ranjith - as noted in the documentation and the blog post I linked to in the answer to this question, `EditText` automatically gets replaced with `AppCompatEditText` when you use `AppCompatActivity` or the equivalent so you wouldn't see a difference - `AppCompatEditText` is only useful if you are building a custom subclass of `EditText` but want the tinting provided by AppCompat.

Comment: TintEditText worked well with appcompat-v7:22.0.0 until I've added the design:22.2.0 that's strange. 
Well this fixes the compile time error but now I've a run time error:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features

Comment: Going from 22.0.0 to 22.2.0 included the very large [Android Support Library 22.1.0 release](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html) - searching for the 'does not support the current theme' brings up the [answer from the author himself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790070/upgraded-to-appcompat-v22-1-0-and-now-getting-illegalargumentexception-appcompa)

Comment: Before I post this question I was able to find Chris Banes's question but his solution didn't work for me. Since I'll only have 2 tabs I've used Google IO approach and it worked. Maybe later in the future if I have to take full advantage of TabLayout I can make it work . Thanks.