# Android Toolbar not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, android-toolbar

I am trying to make a backwards compatible toolbar in Android, and I followed all the suggestions given in multiple style guides to try and accomplish this. However, it's still not seeming to work. Here's the style:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>

    <color name="primary">#da291c</color>
    <color name="primary_dark">#9d1e14</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>

</resources>
```

Here's the toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primary" />
```

And here's the main activity onCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Not quite sure what's wrong, since I'm following all of the instructions that many sources are giving. Here's the log:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features
```

I've been looking at this code, and at countless tutorials and StackOverflow questions, for hours, but to no avail. If someone could help me out, it would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Edit 1:
Here's my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.hackdaytest" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you also paste your manifest file

Comment: Sure, I just did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your styles to this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

or inherit `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
</style>
```

Reference: Chris Banes' post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29790071/566127)

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be working--partially. The app launches without a runtime error, but the toolbar itself is still not displaying. Is there something wrong in the MainActivity.java that prevents the ActionBar from being switched with the toolbar?

Comment: have you `<include/>`d it? Can you post your layout xml?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what that means. Could you explain?

Comment: Can you post your `activity_main.xml` layout? What I am trying to figure out is how you are including the toolbar in your layout.

Comment: Oh wow, never mind. I had the toolbar in a different layout file, so findViewById was returning null. Thanks a lot for your help with the original problem!! :)