# AppCompat does not support the current theme features - nothing works

Tags: android

I'm trying to use MaterialDesign in my project but I'm getting this error all the time:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:371)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.initWindowDecorActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:173)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.getSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:87)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:197)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:99)
        at de.memorian.playpal.MainActivity.afterInject(MainActivity.java:72)
```

I've reade through similar problems but everytime I'm getting the same error.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_main)
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@ViewById
protected Toolbar toolbar;

@AfterInject
public void afterInject() {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
}
```

**styles.xml:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**styles-v21.xml:**

```
style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- enable window content transitions -->
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <!-- specify shared element transitions -->
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
</style>
```

I've tried setting parent theme to any derivation of .NoActionBar, but still. I've also tried removing all code from AndroidAnnotations and doing it the regular way with `setContentView` and `findViewById(R.id.toolbar)`. Only thing that bothers me is that I set `windowNoTitle` to `true` but in the log it says it is `false`.

Any help?

Comment: Check the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653305/full-screen-theme-for-appcompat

Comment: I added them both and it worked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To anyone else having this problem, I just found the problem:
Apparently there exists another theme with name "AppTheme". I don't know why and how, but changing my theme's name solved the problem.

This was the answer to **my** problem.

Comment: worked for me — in my case my project was working, then I brought in a custom view and it started crashing like this. Changing the name resolved the issue. I imagine somewhere in the custom view's gradle import there is a definition of "AppTheme"

Comment: worked after changing from **parent="AppTheme"** to **parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"**

Answer (score 134):

Change:

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

to:

```
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Comment: what is the difference

Comment: in my case it was the opposite of your explanation

Answer (score 1):

Add them on Activity MainActivity in your AndroidManifest.xml  file

like this

```
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the theme.xml file, had set

```
<item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
```

to false.
changed it to true.

```
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

do that if you did this.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and just Rebuilding my project solved the issue. Hope it may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

While migrating to **Material3** I faced the same issue. What you need to do is extend the **NoActionBar** theme.

This:

```
<style name="Theme.AppDefault" parent="@style/Theme.Material3.DayNight">
```

Has to be changed to:

```
<style name="Theme.AppDefault" parent="@style/Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score -2):

Copy this code in your main style:

`<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">`

Comment: why is that such a common answer? looking at the error log, it is explicitly saying the opposite: "windowAcitonBar: false" is _not_ supported.