# video as a splash screen?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, splash-screen

i have created a app which have video as a splash screen , my app work fine on android 6.0 and above but when I run my app on android 5.0 it show  can't play this video after showing this my app goes to mainactivity and it works fine . 
  can you help me showing the video in android 5.0 . my min sdk version is android 4.4 api 19 but my app dont work on android 4.4 it stops , can you help me to make my app work fine on android 4.4 and 5.0

debug log if you need

for android 4.4

```
**

Log messages will follow once session has started...
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onPointerCaptureChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPointerCaptureChanged
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 21560: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onPointerCaptureChanged (Z)V
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 21562: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 21564: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 21568: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1020: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1042: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
D/        ( 3346): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8ee3aa0, tid 3346
D/EGL_emulation( 3346): eglCreateContext: 0xb8ee5f20: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation( 3346): eglMakeCurrent: 0xb8ee5f20: ver 2 0
E/EGL_emulation( 3346): tid 3346: eglSurfaceAttrib(1199): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/HardwareRenderer( 3346): Backbuffer cannot be preserved
D/OpenGLRenderer( 3346): Enabling debug mode 0
D/MediaPlayer( 3346): getMetadata
E/MediaPlayer( 3346): error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer( 3346): Error (1,-2147483648)
D/VideoView( 3346): Error: 1,-2147483648
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 983: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 985: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
E/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 263 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x000c
D/dalvikvm( 3346): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 169K, 7% free 3253K/3484K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
D/dalvikvm( 3346): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 7% free 3473K/3708K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 3346): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.868MB for 2536932-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 3346): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 5950K/6188K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 3ms
D/dalvikvm( 3346): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 2ms
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 22589: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize ()I
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0004
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeMinTextSize, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeMinTextSize
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 22590: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeMinTextSize ()I
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0004
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeStepGranularity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeStepGranularity
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 22591: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeStepGranularity ()I
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0004
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 22592: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes ()[I
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0004
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeTextType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeTextType
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 22593: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeTextType ()I
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0005
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.widget.TextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 22648: Landroid/widget/TextView;.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration (IIII)V
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0004
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.widget.TextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 22649: Landroid/widget/TextView;.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes ([II)V
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0004
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.widget.TextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 22650: Landroid/widget/TextView;.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults (I)V
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0004
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeStepGranularity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 22591: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeStepGranularity ()I
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0161
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.text.StaticLayout$Builder.obtain, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextViewAutoSizeHelper.createStaticLayoutForMeasuring
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve static method 20680: Landroid/text/StaticLayout$Builder;.obtain (Ljava/lang/CharSequence;IILandroid/text/TextPaint;I)Landroid/text/StaticLayout$Builder;
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0014
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 756: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.content.Context.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 747: Landroid/content/Context;.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.content.Context.getCodeCacheDir, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getCodeCacheDir
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 754: Landroid/content/Context;.getCodeCacheDir ()Ljava/io/File;
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.content.Context.getColor, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColor
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 755: Landroid/content/Context;.getColor (I)I
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColorStateList
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 756: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.content.Context.getDataDir, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDataDir
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 758: Landroid/content/Context;.getDataDir ()Ljava/io/File;
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.content.Context.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 761: Landroid/content/Context;.getDrawable (I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.content.Context.getNoBackupFilesDir, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 769: Landroid/content/Context;.getNoBackupFilesDir ()Ljava/io/File;
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.content.Context.isDeviceProtectedStorage, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.isDeviceProtectedStorage
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 782: Landroid/content/Context;.isDeviceProtectedStorage ()Z
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.content.Context.startForegroundService, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.startForegroundService
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 798: Landroid/content/Context;.startForegroundService (Landroid/content/Intent;)Landroid/content/ComponentName;
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.widget.Button.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 22028: Landroid/widget/Button;.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize ()I
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0004
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.widget.Button.getAutoSizeMinTextSize, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.getAutoSizeMinTextSize
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 22029: Landroid/widget/Button;.getAutoSizeMinTextSize ()I
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0004
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.widget.Button.getAutoSizeStepGranularity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.getAutoSizeStepGranularity
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 22030: Landroid/widget/Button;.getAutoSizeStepGranularity ()I
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0004
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.widget.Button.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 22031: Landroid/widget/Button;.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes ()[I
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0004
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.widget.Button.getAutoSizeTextType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.getAutoSizeTextType
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 22032: Landroid/widget/Button;.getAutoSizeTextType ()I
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0005
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.widget.Button.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 22041: Landroid/widget/Button;.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration (IIII)V
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0004
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.widget.Button.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 22042: Landroid/widget/Button;.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes ([II)V
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0004
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find method android.widget.Button.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 22043: Landroid/widget/Button;.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults (I)V
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0004
D/EGL_emulation( 3346): eglMakeCurrent: 0xb8ee5f20: ver 2 0
E/EGL_emulation( 3346): tid 3346: eglSurfaceAttrib(1199): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/HardwareRenderer( 3346): Backbuffer cannot be preserved
D/AndroidRuntime( 3346): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 3346): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x94ceeb20)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346): Process: com.hoogle.quoteslibrary, PID: 3346
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hoogle.quoteslibrary/com.hoogle.quoteslibrary.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:469)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:323)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346):    at com.hoogle.quoteslibrary.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346):    ... 11 more**
```

**for android 5.0 ,5.1**

```
Log messages will follow once session has started...
I/art     ( 3102): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2513(202KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 849KB/1117KB, paused 709us total 126.615ms

D/OpenGLRenderer( 3102): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

D/        ( 3102): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb3ec7a10, tid 3102

D/Atlas   ( 3102): Validating map...

D/        ( 3102): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae0822e0, tid 3119

I/OpenGLRenderer( 3102): Initialized EGL, version 1.4

W/OpenGLRenderer( 3102): Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...

D/EGL_emulation( 3102): eglCreateContext: 0xae034a60: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2

D/EGL_emulation( 3102): eglMakeCurrent: 0xae034a60: ver 2 0

D/OpenGLRenderer( 3102): Enabling debug mode 0

D/EGL_emulation( 3102): eglMakeCurrent: 0xae034a60: ver 2 0

D/MediaPlayer( 3102): getMetadata

W/art     ( 3102): Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

I/art     ( 3102): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 461(38KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 1918KB/3MB, paused 5.934ms total 20.788ms

W/ResourcesManager( 3102): Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.

W/ResourcesManager( 3102): Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.

I/WebViewFactory( 3102): Loading com.android.webview version 39 (4212452-x86) (code 300007)

I/LibraryLoader( 3102): Time to load native libraries: 1 ms (timestamps 7244-7245)

I/LibraryLoader( 3102): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""

V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider( 3102): Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {65917f2}

I/LibraryLoader( 3102): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""

I/chromium( 3102): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(104)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0

I/BrowserStartupController( 3102): Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true

W/art     ( 3102): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring

W/AudioManagerAndroid( 3102): Requires BLUETOOTH permission

W/chromium( 3102): [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(304)] locale_file_path.empty()

I/chromium( 3102): [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(65)] Load from apk succesful, fd=41 off=46184 len=3037

I/chromium( 3102): [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(78)] Loading webviewchromium.pak from, fd:42 off:229484 len:1089587

D/EGL_emulation( 3102): eglCreateContext: 0xa2014f40: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2

D/EGL_emulation( 3102): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa2014f40: ver 2 0

W/chromium( 3102): [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_settings.cc(331)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup

W/art     ( 3102): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring

W/AwContents( 3102): onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

I/Ads     ( 3102): Starting ad request.

I/Ads     ( 3102): This request is sent from a test device.

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

I/Ads     ( 3102): Starting ad request.

I/Ads     ( 3102): This request is sent from a test device.

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

W/Ads     ( 3102): Google Play Service is out of date, the Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firebase integration requires updated Google Play Service.

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

W/Ads     ( 3102): Google Play Service is out of date, the Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firebase integration requires updated Google Play Service.

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

I/Ads     ( 3102): Starting ad request.

I/Ads     ( 3102): This request is sent from a test device.

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

I/Ads     ( 3102): Starting ad request.

I/Ads     ( 3102): This request is sent from a test device.

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

I/Ads     ( 3102): Starting ad request.

I/Ads     ( 3102): This request is sent from a test device.

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

I/Ads     ( 3102): Starting ad request.

I/Ads     ( 3102): This request is sent from a test device.

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

I/Ads     ( 3102): Starting ad request.

I/Ads     ( 3102): This request is sent from a test device.

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

I/Ads     ( 3102): Starting ad request.

I/Ads     ( 3102): This request is sent from a test device.

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

I/Ads     ( 3102): Starting ad request.

I/Ads     ( 3102): This request is sent from a test device.

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

I/Ads     ( 3102): Starting ad request.

I/Ads     ( 3102): This request is sent from a test device.

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

D/zzcz    ( 3102): File /data/data/com.hoogle.quoteslibrary/cache/1521499837408.dex not found. No need for deletion

I/Ads     ( 3102): Starting ad request.

I/Ads     ( 3102): This request is sent from a test device.

E/bf      ( 3102): fd

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3102): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11302270

D/EGL_emulation( 3102): eglMakeCurrent: 0xae034a60: ver 2 0

W/chromium( 3102): [WARNING:simple_index_file.cc(337)] Could not map Simple Index file.

W/art     ( 3102): Long monitor contention event with owner method=java.util.List java.util.Collections.emptyList() from Collections.java:2401 waiters=3 for 145ms

W/art     ( 3102): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring

W/AwContents( 3102): onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring

W/art     ( 3102): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring

W/art     ( 3102): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring

W/art     ( 3102): Long monitor contention event with owner method=java.util.List java.util.Collections.emptyList() from Collections.java:2401 waiters=4 for 170ms

E/MediaPlayer( 3102): error (1, -38)

D/EGL_emulation( 3102): eglMakeCurrent: 0xae034a60: ver 2 0

E/bf      ( 3102): fd

I/chromium( 3102): [INFO:CONSOLE(8)] "The key "viewport-fit" is not recognized and ignored.", source: https://www.brainyquote.com/topics/love (8)
```

Comment: can you post the code to show video in your app ?

Comment: you asked for these code https://www.sendspace.com/file/hnolyb

Answer (score 0):

You should look at line where is says :

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346): Process: com.hoogle.quoteslibrary, PID: 3346
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hoogle.quoteslibrary/com.hoogle.quoteslibrary.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }
```

The third line ends with:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }
```

It seems a problem of Theme to fix in styles.xml
For example look at [AppCompat does not support the current theme features - nothing works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32614064/appcompat-does-not-support-the-current-theme-features-nothing-works/32902509)

Comment: **styles.xml:**    [https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Gwuh06VZLgc7_9q7YZr69U4oOx53UfGe]     check my style code for me im not able to find whats the error

Comment: Your link doesn't work. Try to copy first two rows of styles.xml file content?

Comment: **styles.xml(at bottom of the file ) : ** https://www.sendspace.com/file/hnolyb       pls check my style code . this link works

Comment: try to add these two items to style "AppTheme.NoActionBar":<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

Comment: **E/AndroidRuntime( 2949): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.  **  after the change in style.xml debug shows this error in  android 4.4

Answer (score 0):

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 3346): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }
```

**The easiest way to solve the above issue is to put:-**
 `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` as your parent theme. 
**otherwise put this in style**

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>

</style>
```

**Check this edited style**

Comment: **E/AndroidRuntime( 2949): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.  **  after the change in style.xml debug shows this error in  android 4.4

Comment: @anshul i checked your code but it is working fine with me. i have edited the style please use that style and let me know, that issue exist

Comment: it worked for me thanks for your help but still video is do not start it show cant play the video, this error is in android below 6.0

Comment: @anshul try another video because i checked with a video in android 6.0 below , which is working fine. if my answer is correct then accept and mark as correct

Comment: thanks bro for your help bro .  will you teach me android studio ? . can we get connected on gmail ? , my email id anshul348567890123@gmail.com  . i need some more help from you .

Comment: @anshul Ok please mark  this answer as accepted. You can find a tick mark below down and up vote