# android app's theme is not inheriting its parent's theme

Tags: android-theme, android-styles

I am having this style:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->


</style>
```

Of course, in the manifest I have:

```
   <application
        android:name=".MyAppApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme" >
```

I am trying to implement material design toolbar following this article: [www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html#](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html#)

Now, if I'm leaving everything as above, I get:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action
>   bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request
>   Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your
>   theme to use a Toolbar instead.

But if I'm changing my style to this:

```
 <!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->


</style>
```

i.e., the parent is directly `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` then everything works without the error message.

Can anyone see what am I missing? why is that so?

Comment: Could I see your activity code?

Comment: @NickHargreaves Sure Nick, you can see it in the SO question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254840/why-do-android-insists-that-i-already-have-action-bar . Changing the parent theme was the solution I found to my problem there. However, it still puzzles me. Thank you very much.