# inflating activity content fails in instrumentation

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I am trying to setup espresso in a project.
I created a new empty activity project in Android Studio (1.5.1)
It has no problems running

added the espresso configurations to the project and a test class.

When running the test I am getting

```
  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030015
  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1266)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2649)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1082)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:412)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:358)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:279)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:253)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
  at com.adi.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
  at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:494)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

BTW the ID is for the toolbar

The test class is

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

   @Rule
   public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule =
        new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

   @Test
   public void test(){}
}
```

gradle.build is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.adi"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to remove  `androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'`, sync, clean. Other code looks fine for me.

Comment: denys, removing this causes a conflict between main apk and test apk.

Comment: @denys That's the exactly reason cause my similar problem!

Answer (score 0):

I've already found on StackOverflow site similar problem. Take a look at this Chris Banes explanation and solution:

> AppCompat is now more strict on what it expect in theme window flags,
>   more closely matching what you would get from the framework.
>
> The main reason behind this is to support
>   [AppCompatDialogs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDialog.html)
>   which we were also adding in this release. They make heavy use of the
>   `windowNoTitle` flag, which AppCompat previously didn't pay much
>   attention to.
>
> So to fix your issue you have two options:
>
> The easy way is to just use `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` as your
>   parent theme. This will always do the right thing.
>
> If you can't do that though (maybe you need to support action bar and
>   no action bar), you should do the following:
>
> ```
> <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
>     ...
> </style>
>
> <style name="MyTheme.NoActionBar">
>     <!-- Both of these are needed -->
>     <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
>     <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
> </style>
> ```
>
> You should be back on track now.
>
> From: [Upgraded to AppCompat v22.1.0 and now getting IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790070/upgraded-to-appcompat-v22-1-0-and-now-getting-illegalargumentexception-appcompa)

As you would notice, you don't need to delete from your `build.gradle` file `support.v7...` dependencies. Just make some changes in your `Activity` theme.

EDIT: Change also `buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"` to `23.0.2` version.

Hope it help

Comment: thanks for the response, tried all suggestions but still doesn't work... in any case I need the action bar.