# AutoCompleteTextView setError

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, autocompletetextview

[image: Image Description]

Password field is `AutoCompleteTextView` and I'm trying to do `setError` when it's empty, but I don't want this red exclamation mark to show. How should I do this?

P.S. field on top of this, is also `AutoCompleteTextView`, (mailview) but when I do `setError` when it's empty, red exclamation mark doesn't show.

Comment: what version are you using com.android.support: library ?

Comment: com.android.support....24.2.0

Comment: try with lower version to 23. it will work

Comment: wow, thanks, one extra exclamation mark doesn't show anymore but is there any chance to disappear second too?

Comment: now I found out that after changing I've got exception about NavigationView is there any way out?

Comment: what is exception ?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.azry.rbs/com.azry.rbs.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Comment: this is other exception of NavigationView not regarding

Comment: yes it absolutely different, but when I changed android support version back it worked but in this case password field does not work.... yeah of course I'll accet

Comment: you can ask me if you are stuck there.

Comment: Possibly related to or same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674636/eye-indicator-overlaps-hint-error-icon-in-autocompletetextview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that, you need to use **`com.android.support....23.0.0`**.

as well as dont use `setError` so that extra exclamation will not appear instead use some other way to show error.

according to me, this is a **bug** on updating to `com.android.support....24.0.0` in `TextInputLayout` as password and `setError` exclamation will be overrite.

you should use only one of them.

Comment: now I've got new exception, on class which extends preferenceActivity   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790070/upgraded-to-appcompat-v22-1-0-and-now-getting-illegalargumentexception-appcompa

Comment: use **Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar** as your parent theme

Comment: :/ still crashing and have same exception

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `setError` method like this:

```
setError("Error", null)
```