# Eye indicator overlaps Hint error icon in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, material-design

Code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:hint="@string/current_password"
    android:paddingEnd="14dp"
    android:paddingLeft="14dp"
    android:paddingRight="14dp"
    android:paddingStart="14dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
    android:textColorHint="@color/darkBlue"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/actvCurrPass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        tools:ignore="Deprecated,RtlHardcoded" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Result when calling `AutoCompleteTextView#setError` or `AutoCompleteTextView#error`:
[image]

[image]

Comment: When you use `TextInputLayout`, you're supposed to call `setError()` on the `TextInputLayout` itself, instead of the `EditText`, in your case, the `AutoCompleteTextView`. The error will appear below the `AutoCompleteTextView`

Comment: @MikeM. I tried this. Now it is showing line below it and no error text. How can I show the error text ?

Comment: @MikeM. I changed it to `TextInputEditText` and added `app:errorEnabled="true"` in `TextInputLayout`. Still it is showing only line when `setError` is called for `TextInputLayout`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "line", but maybe the error text's color is blending in with the background. You might try changing the text color in a style set as the `TextInputLayout`'s `errorTextAppearance`.

Comment: I have updated the answer with screenshot. I am getting line. How to add text error?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use setError() on TextInputLayout instead of EditText.

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout);
textInputLayout.setError("Password cannot be empty.");
```