# How can I add padding to passwordToggleEnabled in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am using "passwordToggleEnabled" and in my java code "setError" but in my result both overlap. Any idea how to add a padding? No matter the width because the same thing happens.

Example xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/edtconfirmText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtPassText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10px">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/confirmPass"
            android:layout_width="580px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[Look result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg4tb.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EditText error icon and show password missplaced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39313026/edittext-error-icon-and-show-password-missplaced) or [Eye indicator overlaps Hint error icon in AutoCompleteTextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674636/eye-indicator-overlaps-hint-error-icon-in-autocompletetextview)

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use TextInputLayout's setError method instead of EditText setError