# Disable a Android Title

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

1.Hello , i am trying to build a webView Full Screen App 
But i can't understand how to disable the title bar 
I change the theme in my manifest to this : Android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >`

But that still keep showing me that Title .

2.From sdk 6 there is a like a email icon on the right bottom
of the app,there is way to disable that too ?

Thanks for all the help !!

code :

Manifest 
:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.omermalka.webview" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

main Activity :

```
package com.example.omermalka.webview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        /*FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });*/
        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        webView.loadUrl("https://pizzahut.co.il");
    }
    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Activity.XML
:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks again to all the helpers

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863676/android-activity-without-actionbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` in your activity before `setContentView(LayoutId);` to hide **title**.

**Note:**
Reference to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250149/requestfeature-must-be-called-before-adding-content) in `AppCompact` and `ActionBarSherkock` libraries you should put `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` before `super.onCreate();`.

**Or**

you can put this code into styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and in your manifest file put below code in your activity tag

```
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

Like

```
        <activity
            android:name=".RSSActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_rss"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
```

Comment: i tried to do that , every time that i run its crash the app and write a msg "Unfortunately ,WebView has stopped"

Comment: Be sure to put it before setConetntView.

Comment: it is before the setConetntView , still crashing

Comment: still Crashing
with the msg 
""Unfortunately ,WebView has stopped""

Comment: put the logcat in the question to review what's problem, maybe it's from other thing

Comment: In android studio, in the bottom the is button that's name is Android Monitor. Press it, there's written why the problem is occured. Copy past the red results here